# O que é callback?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, callback

Vejo em muitos códigos e até mesmo arquiteturas a palavra callback, vejo que é em funções JavaScript.

- Mas o que é?
- Como é usada?
- Por que?

Gostaria de um exemplo de uso real.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Callback é uma função que é usada como "callback". Ela é tipicamente passada como argumento de outra função e/ou chamada quando um evento for acontecido, ou quando uma parte de código receber uma resposta de que estava à espera.

Isto é muito comum em javascript lado cliente e servidor (NodeJS) mas não só. A função callback é muitas vezes assíncrona na medida em que é chamada como consequência de outro código que esta a correr no background. A grande vantagem é que assim o computador pode ir processando outros processos enquanto a resposta não chega e não precisa assim de parar tudo à espera dessa resposta.

Um exemplo clássico é um auscultador de eventos que chama uma função quando o evento acontece:

```
function callback(e) {
    alert('Aconteceu um evento ' + e.type);
}
window.addEventListener('click', callback);
```

Este callback vai ser chamada quando fizer um click na janela. Até isso acontecer o processador vai processando outras coisas que acontecem na aplicação.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/D2PuH/

---

Outro exemplo é uma chamada de ajax, que faz um pedido ao servidor e corre a função quando receber a resposta.

Essa função é uma função "callback". No exemplo em baixo (http://jsfiddle.net/skQr7/) chamei-lhe `minhaCallBack`.

```
function minhaCallBack(returnhtml) {
    $("#result").html(returnhtml);
    $("#loadingimg").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form_url,
            type: form_method,
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            success: minhaCallBack
        }); 
});
```

---

Outro exemplo ainda (http://jsfiddle.net/V3wDF/) é uma animação que chama a callback no fim da animação estar completa:

```
function completa() {
    alert('Este alert está dentro da função "callback"');
}
$('div').animate({
    'height': '200px'
}, {
    duration: 2000,
    complete: completa
});
```

---

## Outro exemplo ainda, para tentar clarificar mais depois de surgir [mais uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205819/callbacks-que-n%C3%A3o-entram-na-minha-mente#comment421146_205819).

Vou fazer uma analogia entre código síncrono e código assíncrono.
Imaginando esta situação:

#### Problema:

> Como transformar um numero no formato string, com parte decimal longa demais que deve ser convertido em dólares, e verificar se um dado cliente têm direito a desconto.

#### Solução síncrona:

Para resolver este problema de forma síncrona temos de saber o valor inicial e o valor do câmbio **antes** de iniciarmos o cálculo. Isto nem sempre é assim, mas para o exemplo vamos assumir que sabemos o seguinte:

```
var valorInicial = "1003,087293487";
var descontoCliente = "5%";
var cambio =  1.1158; // 1 EUR = 1.11580USD
```

assim podemos fazer a transformação de maneira simples:

```
var valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico = Number(valorInicial.replace(',', '.'));
var valorComDescontoAplicado = valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico - (valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico * parseFloat(descontoCliente) / 100);
var valorEmDolares = valorComDescontoAplicado * cambio;
var totalComDuasCasasDecimais = valorEmDolares.toFixed(2);
```

Assim o resultado é obtido com passos síncronos, e dá `1063.28`

#### Solução assíncrona:

Imagina agora que precisamos de fazer a mesma coisa, mas não temos a informação toda disponível, pois os câmbios mudam constantemente, não podemos ter disponível o desconto de todos os possíveis clientes, e nem mesmo o preço inicial pois temos de perguntar ao nosso fornecedor primeiro.

**Como fazer?**

Neste caso temos de fazer a coisa assíncrona, ou seja correndo parte do código, esperar por respostas, correr mais um pedaço e esperar por outra resposta, etc...

Podemos dizer que quando ***perguntamos*** algo a um serviço exterior fazemos provavelmente um pedido ajax. E agora precisamos de uma ferramenta para receber a resposta, é aí que callbacks entram em jogo.

Quando envio uma pergunta para um serviço externo tenho de lhe dizer como ele me deve contactar/informar com o resultado. Uma maneira comum é enviar uma função com o pedido para que ela seja corrida quando a resposta chegar.

> *enviar uma função com o pedido para que ela seja corrida quando a resposta chegar*

Se eu enviar uma função a um setTimeout, digo ao `setTimeout` qual o código a correr quando o tempo tiver esgotado. Essa função pode ter o nome que quisermos, mas a sua funcionalidade, o seu tipo é **callback**:

```js
var fazerAlgo = function(){ alert('O tempo chegou ao fim!'); }
setTimeout(fazerAlgo, 2000); // correr ao fim de 2 segundos
```

**Voltando ao exemplo das contas:**

para fazermos o cálculo anterior com lógica assíncrona temos de encadear as coisas e depender de funções que vão sendo chamadas com tempos de espera entre elas. Assim temos de encadear tudo, por exemplo assim:

```js
pedirPrecoAoFornecedor(numeroProduto, function(respostaDoFornecedor) {
  var valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico = Number(respostaDoFornecedor.replace(',', '.'));
  pedirInformacaoDesconto(numeroCliente, function(descontoCliente) {
    var valorComDescontoAplicado = valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico - (valorInicialEmFormatoNumerico * parseFloat(descontoCliente) / 100);
    pedirCambioDaHora('USD', function(valorDoDolar) {
      var valorEmDolares = valorComDescontoAplicado * valorDoDolar;
      var totalComDuasCasasDecimais = valorEmDolares.toFixed(2);

      // !! agora temos o resultado!! 
      alert(totalComDuasCasasDecimais + 'USD');

    })
  })
})
```

Este encadeamento de funções é necessário pois cada callback será chamada quando o serviço externo quiser. Por exemplo a função `pedirPrecoAoFornecedor` recebe dois argumentos: o numero do produto e uma função. Como eu sei que o que vou receber é o preço do produto coloco já isso como nome da variável, para facilitar a leitura. Essa função que passo a `pedirPrecoAoFornecedor` é portanto uma callback, um mecanismo para o serviço externo me poder devolver o que preciso.

Comment: +1 excelente resposta, exemplos para tu, devias escrever um livro :P

Comment: Ficou bem explicado, obrigado!

Comment: Muito boa essa explicação, parabéns.

Answer (score 64):

**CallBack** (ou *chamada de retorno*, em português) é um mecanismo de controle de fluxo que visa beneficiar processos assíncronos.

A idéia principal é liberar a aplicação para que outras ações sejam tomadas sem que ela fique aguardando o retorno de processos síncronos, esperando uma resposta remota, ou (caso a plataforma/*framework* em uso suporte *threading*) com alto consumo de processamento se você abriu uma *thread* separada para esperar pela resposta.

Em um mecanismo tradicional, a solicitação síncrona (e consequente espera) por um recurso seria assim em pseudocódigo:

```
Var B = A.SoliciteRecurso();
Print B.Nome;
```

Vamos dizer que operações dentro de `SoliciteRecurso()` tomam um minuto. neste caso, sua aplicação ficará todo este tempo esperando pela resposta.

Agora, uma operação assíncrona via CallBack:

```
Objeto.AssinarRetornoDeSoliciteRecurso += ProcessarRetorno;
Var B = A.SoliciteRecursoAssincrono();

função ProcessarRetorno(Objeto B)
{
    Print B.Nome;
}
```

Neste caso, o controle da aplicação é retornado logo após o método `SoliciteRecursoAssincrono()`. Quando, e se, o objeto `A` gerar o evento que dispara `AssinarRetornoDeSoliciteRecurso`, o método `ProcessarRetorno` será chamado.

Várias tecnologias modernas se utilizam deste recurso. Por exemplo, este snippet em `AngularJS`:

```
function directoryController($scope, $http) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.url = 'backend/services/dir.aspx?q=';

    $scope.search = function() {
        $http.post($scope.url + $scope.keywords).
            success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.listOfUsers = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
    };
```

Basicamente diz:

- No método `search`, acesse essa URL via método `Post`.
- Caso bem sucedido (evento `success`), proceda desta maneira.
- Caso um erro tenha ocorrido (evento `error`), proceda desta outra maneira.

Os benefícios trazidos por chamadas assíncronas são claros: Você tem uma aplicação mais responsiva e com menor consumo de processamento.

Por outro lado, introduz novos paradigmas que você precisa tratar no seu código, como controle assíncrono de fluxo (por exemplo, 'só avance caso tenha recebido o retorno bem-sucedido do método *M*.')

Answer (score 31):

Quando um evento (clique sobre um botão, carregamento da página concluído, mouse sobre um elemento qualquer, etc.) acontece, o browser avisa todos os ouvintes (listeners), **chamando suas funções de calback**.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    console.log("Eu sou uma função de callback, prazer!");
});
```

No exemplo acima, adicionamos um ouvinte de evento "onload" na janela (ou seja, requisitamos que o browser chame nossa função anônima - `function(){...}` - assim que a página terminar de carregar na memória do computador do usuário).

Basicamente, podemos fazer muitas coisas com uma função de callback: trocar um texto na página, esconder elementos, entre muitos outros usos.

Answer (score 9):

> Mas o que é?

Uma função de *callback* é aquela função que pode ser chamada pelo método que a recebe no momento que este desejar.

Em uma pseudo linguagem, seria algo assim:

```
funcao(Function funcaoCallback) {
    // funcao faz diversas coisas
    funcaoCallback.call(); // chama a função passada por parâmetro
}
```

Este conceito é comumente associado à linguagem Javascript devido a popularidade desta linguagem, pois desde os seus primórdios o Javascript aceita a passagem de métodos como parâmetro para uma função. Outras linguagens de programação populares só vieram a ter este tipo de características muito anos depois, como ocorreu com o Java.

> Como é usada?

Existem diferentes maneiras de usar ela em cada linguagem e, conceitualmente, ela pode ser usada de incontáveis maneiras.

Vamos a um exemplo em Java. No Java 8 você pode passar um método de qualquer classe para um método que aceita o parâmetro `Supplier`. Imaginando que temos este método em uma classe chamada `RetryMethod`:

```
public void run(Supplier<T> callbackFunction) throws Exception {
    try {
        // código fazendo inúmeras coisas
        callbackFunction.get(); //chamada da função recebida por parâmetro
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Command failed", e);
        return retry(function);
    }
}
```

E para passar a **função** para este método:

```
RetryMethod<Object> retryMethod = new RetryMethod<>();
retryMethod.run(() -> service.metodoChamadoPorCallback(qualquerParametro));
```

Assim, seja lá o que o método `metodoChamadoPorCallback` faz dentro da classe com nome de variável `service`, o método `run` da classe `RetryMethod` tem o total controle de quando chamá-la.

> Por que?

Como disse anterioremente, as possibilidades são inúmeras.

No exemplo acima, o código usado pode dar o controle para a classe `RetryMethod` do método `metodoChamadoPorCallback` ser chamado diferentes vezes em caso de uma `Exception` dentro dele, fazendo várias tentativas (*retries*). Esta classe `RetryMethod` poderia receber qualquer tipo de função no qual o objetivo seja repetir a chamada da função passada para `callback`, sem se importar com o que a função faça.