# Como aplico o slideDown() junto com o load()

Tags: jquery, animação

Tenho uma página, em que ela exibe conteúdos dinâmicos utilizando o `load()`. Como aplicar o efeito `slideDown()` quando documento é exibido na página?

Meu código está assim:

**index.php**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Documentos
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-page="2" title="Todos">Todos</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" id="nread" data-page="0" title="Não lidos">Não lidos<span class="badge"><?php echo $new_doc ?></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-page="1" title="Lidos">Lidos</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        
    <div class="col-md-9">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <span id="page-title">Todos</span>
         </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Enviado em</th>
                   <th>Documento</th>
                   <th>Vencimento</th>
                   <th></th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**ShowFiles.js**

```
$('.list-group a').click(function() {
     $('tbody').load('view/read.php', function() {
            $(this).slideDown();
       });
       $('.list-group-item').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#page-title').html(title_page);
}
```

**read.php**

```
<tr>
    <td class="1">03/09/2014 14:32:55</td>
    <td>Nome do documento</td>
    <td>10/09/2014</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo "<a href='view/showFile.php?token=" . $token . "&reg=" . $result['reg'] . "' title='Vizualizar' target='_blank' class='btn btn-default view' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-open'></span></a>" ?>
        <span><?php echo "<a href='action/downloadFile.php?token=" . $token . "&reg=" . $result['reg'] . "' title='Download' class='btn btn-default download' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span></a>" ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem de usar a [callback do `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Exemplo:

```
$('tbody').load('view/read.php', function() {
  $(this).slideDown()
});
```

[Callback é uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) que é chamada pelo próprio método do jQuery. Dessa maneira o elemento recebe o novo conteudo e só depois faz o slideDown.

Dentro dessa função o código será corrido uma vez por elemento que estiver no seletor antes do `.load()`, ou seja `$('tbody')`, e o `this` será atribuído a esse(s) elemento(s).

Comment: Po amigão, não funcionou :(  Tem alguma coisa, que possa esta impedindo?

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 tem algum erro na consola? O conteudo está a carregar bem? Pode descrever melhor o que não funciona?

Comment: No console não tem nenhum erro, o conteúdo está sendo mostrado normalmente com e sem este callback. Vou editar minha pergunta colocando o meu código inteiro.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47, aqui na Suécia está na hora de dormir. Se colocar o seu HTML correspondente ao código eu (ou outro aqui no site) posso re-criar o que tem no jsFiddle e mostrar um exemplo a funcionar. Talvez aí dê para perceber o erro...

Comment: Beleza, vou colocar aqui mesmo