# Como recuperar um valor dentro da função setTimeout com jquery?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando recuperar um valor dentro da função setTimeout para fazer um cálculo mais o resultado é totalmente diferente do que eu esperava.

```
var aux = '1.056,00';

//Retiro a formatação da moeda.
aux = aux.replace('.', '');
aux = aux.replace(',', '.');

var vlr_unitario = setTimeout(function(){
    aux;
},10);

alert(vlr_unitario);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Quero recuperar um valor que está dentro da função setTimeout.

```
var unitario_aux = ($("#valor_unitario").val() === '') ? 0 : $("#valor_unitario").val(); //Retiro a formatação da moeda do valor_unitario. 
unitario_aux = unitario_aux.replace('.', '');
unitario_aux = unitario_aux.replace(',', '.');
var vlr_unitario = 0;
var idTimeOut = setTimeout(function () {
    vlr_unitario = unitario_aux;
    clearTimeout(idTimeOut);
}, 10);
alert(vlr_unitario);
```

Comment: Você quer atribuir o valor da aux na variável vlr_unitario?

Comment: Bruno, porque então utilizar o setTimeout? se você que o retorno logo depois do método? Imagine assim, a parte do setTimeout so vai acontecer depois de 10 milisegundos, mas a próxima linha já vai ter sido executada, daí a lógica está errada.

Comment: Bruno explica melhor o que queres fazer, isso pode passar por outra funcionalidade que o `setTimeout`.

Comment: Compreendo a sua lógica Guilherme, mais o que acontece é que está função que estou desenvolvendo, ela é muito dinâmica e existe uma função de formatação de moeda(priceFormat) então toda vez que altero o campo valor_unitario essa função é executada dai a sigla 'R$' vem junto com o valor dai o cálculo me da errado. Retorna o erro: NaN pq a função está tentando fazer um cálculo com string e numeros. entendeu?

Comment: @BrunoDuarte explica o que queres fazer e mostra o código que já tens. Vais ver que a solução para o problema surge e talvez vais aprender maneiras novas de o fazer.

Comment: Quero recuperar um valor que está dentro da função setTimeout.var unitario_aux = ($("#valor_unitario").val() === '') ? 0 : $("#valor_unitario").val();
        
        //Retiro a formatação da moeda do valor_unitario.
        unitario_aux = unitario_aux.replace('.', '');
        unitario_aux = unitario_aux.replace(',', '.');
        
        var vlr_unitario = 0;
        var idTimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
            vlr_unitario = unitario_aux;
           clearTimeout(idTimeOut);
        },10);
        alert(vlr_unitario);

Comment: E qual é a ideia por detrás do `setTimeout`? porque não uma funcionalidade tipo callback?

Comment: @Sergio - Analisando o meu código eu percebi a caca que eu estava fazendo. Já consegui conserta o erro aqui. É que quando eu altero o campo valor_unitario essa função é executada dai a sigla 'R$' que vem de uma mascara(priceFormat) vem junto com o valor dai o cálculo me da errado. Mais agora eu retirei essa sigla com o replace e funcionou perfeitamente. Agradeço a sua atenção e a de todos que opinaram.

Comment: @BrunoDuarte nõ tem problema, estamos todos aqui porque gostamos de resolver problemas e aprender uns com os outros. O que eu queria era ter 100% certeza que percebí a pergunta e deixar uma resposta com uma solução. E para isso precisas de juntar o código todo que tens, pois sem perceber o que queres fazer é dificil ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Basta que você setar o valor da variável lá dentro do escopo da função.

O retorno da função setTimeout é um número, representando o valor do ID do timer que foi setado.

PS.: No seu caso, como o `alert` está fora, ele exibe o resultado antes de que a função timeout execute. Note que no código abaixo o alert ficou dentro do código da função `setTimeout`

```js
    var aux = '1.056,00';
    
    //Retiro a formatação da moeda.
    aux = aux.replace('.', '');
    aux = aux.replace(',', '.');
    
    var vlr_unitario = 0;

    setTimeout(function(){
        vlr_unitario = aux;          
        alert(vlr_unitario);
    },10);
```

Comment: Só `setInterval` é executado "sem parar", `setTimeout` é só executado uma vez a cada vez que você chamar, `clearTimeout` serve para "cancelar" o evento em espera do `setTimeout`, por exemplo o seu código estiver assim `var timer = setTimeout(caller, 10000);` vai levar dez segundos para a função ser chamada, se no quinto segundo você executar `clearTimeout(timer);` ele não irá executar o `caller`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Feito!

Comment: Nossa @Caputo me perdoe, agora que eu entendi, eu não havia me dado conta, pode fazer um rollback na resposta. Perdoe a gafe. Vale até um positivo a sua resposta está certíssima.

Answer (score 1):

A função `setTimeout` é considerada "assíncrona" (lembrando o Thread de outras linguagens) e por isto o que é executado dentro dela está a parte dos demais eventos.

Porém você pode acessar a variável dentro dela, mas as outras funções só poderão acessar depois do "timeout" tiver sido concluído e o evento dentro dele tiver terminado (acaso haja "loops" longos).

Para mais detalhes por favor leia está resposta [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635)

### Entendendo o acesso das variáveis

`var vlr_unitario;` seja uma variável de "level superior", por exemplo:

```
//level global
var variavelglobal;

function A() {
   //superior a todos
   var variavel_acessivel_em_A_B_C;

   var B = function () {
       //infeior a "A", mas superior a "C"
       var variavel_acessivel_em_B_C;

       var C = function () {
           //infeior a A e B
           var variavel_acessivel_em_C;
       };
       C();
   };
   B();
}
```

- `C` pode ter acesso as variáveis em `B` e `A`
- `B` pode ter acesso as variáveis em `A`
- `A` só pode ter acesso as variáveis no "level superior"
- `variavelglobal` é acessível por todas

### setTimeout

Tendo entendido isto, agora irei explicar sobre eventos com "timeout". Estes eventos como `setTimeout` e `setInterval` são executado a parte, semelhante a eventos assíncronos, quando você chama:

```
var test = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
   test += 1; //Soma mais um
}, 1);
alert(test); //Test irá mostrar "zero"
```

O resultado é zero, pois o evento foi executado só depois de "um milissegundo", quando é chamado `alert(test)` a variável ainda não recebeu o valor e por operar de maneira "assíncrona" o `setTimeout` não trava o processo até completar o `setTimeout`, como faz o `sleep` em outras linguagens.

Note que em linguagens como `PHP` temos a função chamada `sleep(5);`, ela é diferente de `setTimeout`, quando `sleep` é executado assim:

```
echo '1';
sleep(5);
echo '2';
```

O processo é "travado" até ser concluído o `sleep(...);` o `2` não será mostrado, ou seja isto é síncrono.

- **Q:** É possível fazer "sleep" em JavaScript, mas por que não fazemos?
- **R:** Por que iria travar o "motor" do navegador e a janela iria congelar (por milissegundos ou segundos)

Essa é "uma" das vantagens do JavaScript, ActionScript e outras linguagens [ECMASript](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), poder trabalhar de maneira "assíncrona". Veja um exemplo "Ajax" é assíncrono, existe "Ajax síncrono", mas isto é um "mal caminho".

### Como usar o acesso de variáveis junto ao setTimeout

Se você tiver um código assim (leia os comentários dentro do código):

```
function main() {
    var variavel = 1;

    //Espera um segundo
    setTimeout(function () {
        variavel += 1;
    }, 1000);

    //Espera dois segundos
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Mostra "2"; pois esperou mais que o tempo do outro setTimeout
        alert(variavel);
    }, 1000);

    //mostra "1" pois não houve espera
    alert(variavel);
}

window.onload = main;
```

Ou seja o ultimo `alert` não esperou o `setTimeout` concluir e por isto exibiu `1`.

### A solução

Para conseguir usar "a solução" você terá que trabalhar com "callbacks", para entender leia esta resposta do [StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback), após entender, leia o que vem a seguir (só depois que entender mesmo rs):

Suponho que o valor `1.056,00` venha de um `<INPUT>` e você queira enviar ele para um `<div>` (ou ajax, ou qualquer coisa que receba essa informação), você poderá executar desta maneira:

> Nota: eu só usei um DIV como exemplo, você pode usar para ajax ou o que necessitar

```js
var elementoInput = document.getElementById("MEU_INPUT");
var elementoDiv = document.getElementById("MEU_DIV");
var botaoTest = document.getElementById("TEST");
var vlr_unitario;

function atualizarDiv() {
   elementoDiv.innerHTML = vlr_unitario;
}

function transformarEmDecimal() {
    var aux = elementoInput.value;//Pega o valor
    
    //Retiro a formatação da moeda.
    aux = aux.replace('.', '');
    aux = aux.replace(',', '.');

    elementoDiv.innerHTML = "Carregando...";
    setTimeout(function(){
        vlr_unitario = aux;

        //Chama a função
        atualizarDiv();
    }, 1000);
}

botaoTest.onclick = transformarEmDecimal;
```

```html
<input id="MEU_INPUT" type="text" value="1.056,00">
<div id="MEU_DIV">vazio</div>
<input id="TEST" type="button" value="Testar">
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme Nascimento?
Desde já agradeço pela a sua atenção!
Eu consegui compreender o que vc quis me dizer e até deu certo, a função retornou o valor correto. Mais só que eu preciso acessar externamente o valor da variável 'vlr_unitario' que está dentro da função setTimeout entendeu? Para que eu possa fazer os cálculos.
Por isso que eu coloquei o alert fora da função. Pra mim ver como a variável 'vlr_unitario' se comportava, mais mesmo desse jeito que vc descreveu não esta funcionando ele retorna o valor inicial da variável que é '0'.
Entendeu?

Comment: @BrunoDuarte sim isto está claro, mas a minha resposta diz exatamente o que você tem que fazer: É aprender a usar "callbacks" e trabalhar usando eles, poste mais do seu código para você eu ver se consigo lhe fornecer um exemplo funcional nele mesmo.