# Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, callback

Tem muita explicação do que é callback pela net e até alguns exemplos escassos, mas nada que explique **na prática** e detalhadamente um uso realmente importante (eu não achei).

Eu já entendi um pouco de como usar e até fiz [minha versão](http://jsfiddle.net/um9gszcd/2/) de um exemplo que achei na net, no entanto, o mesmo pode ser replicado sem uso de callback e funcionar igual ou até melhor

Estou tentando me introduzir nos conceitos e padrões do Node.js que é repleto disso: multithread, callback, assincronismo etc, mas enquanto eu não entender realmente para que serve um callback ou o que é uma thread acho que nunca vou aprender Node.js de verdade.

Gostaria de exemplos simples e/ou algum exemplo clássico e imprescindível em Node.js já que é meu foco.

**Nota**: Estudo programação há apenas 7 meses e até agora só mexi no client-side, a minha jornada ao back-end é recente. Isso pode ser útil para forjar a resposta.

Comment: Porquê `-2` nesta pergunta?

Comment: *Como assim "sem callback", ambos exemplos tem "callback"*? Não fui eu quem negativou, mas suponho que este seja o motivo. **Nota:** *Callback* é algo que está na "alma" dos códigos ECMAScript, não trabalhar com *Callback* nele é o mesmo que "limitar" quase todos suas funcionalidades, em outras palavras, não é questão de *vantagem*, é como a linguagem funciona na maior parte dos códigos javascript. **Nota 2:** Ambos exemplos seus usam callback, você só não conseguiu perceber.

Comment: @Sergio pois é, também não entendi. Talvez tenham achado que o titulo remetia à dois assuntos distintos... em fim...

Comment: Talvez você esteja ignorando meu comentário amigo, mas só digo isto: Até aonde você pensa que não aplicou callback, você aplicou, você só não percebeu. Aquilo dentro do `setTimeout` nos dois exemplos são "callbacks". Portanto o primeiro exemplo tem 2 callbacks, o segundo apenas um callback.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu sei que apliquei callback no `setTimeout` mas a questão é apresentar a "estrutura" feita por mim e não o `setTimeout`. Eu devia ter tirado ele...

Comment: @ropbla9 Aquela maneira que você trabalhou é útil quando o código trabalha de maneira ASSÍNCRONA, assim evitando congelamento do motor, quase tudo em ECMAScript é preferível trabalhar de maneira assíncrona, assim uma execução não vai precisar esperar a outra responder e as duas vão poder trabalhar lado a lado. Nota: Em um código que faz uma grande rotina e leva algum tempo, isto pode evitar que outros códigos tenham que esperar ele terminar (claro que tem que saber implementar isto).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, poderia me escrever uma resposta?

Comment: [Esta minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programação-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript/16960#16960) talvez te ajude.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O maior processo do Javascript é considero um único evento. Se você executar uma longa operação dentro deste evento o processo pode travar por alguns instantes o navegador (ou outro software que use ECMAScript), então o processo irá parar de processar outros eventos até que complete a sua operação e provavelmente irá congelar o navegador.

Por exemplo se você usar `XMLHttpRequest` desta maneira:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'url_arquivo_grande', false); //false = síncrono
xhr.send(null);
alert(xhr.responseText);
alert('Outra tarefa...');//Isto iria demorar de aparecer e provavelmente o navegador irá congelar
```

O processo principal do navegador irá ficar travado até que o servidor termine de enviar a resposta para o cliente e o cliente (cliente no caso é o navegador) processe está resposta.

Portanto em `XMLHttpRequest` costumamos usar `AJAX` (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) que seria a maneira assíncrona dele, que seria algo como:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'url_arquivo_grande', true); //true = assincrono
xhr.onreadystachange = function () { alert(xhr.responseText); };
xhr.send(null);
alert('Outra tarefa...');//Isto não espera o ajax
```

Você não necessita usar `callback` para tudo, porém se o seu código tiver uma grande chance de bloquear/congelar as demais operações é essencial que você utilize métodos assíncronos, ou até mesmo `setTimeout`.

### O que realmente nos leva ao callback

Se o código for demorado (mesmo que não se trate de `XMLHttpRequest`), vale você recorrer a um `setTimeout`, a partir deste momento você *não* conseguirá usar o `return ...`, então será necessário usar o `callback`.

Porém é como eu disse, não há necessidade de usar callback em tudo, apenas aonde será necessário eventos assíncronos.

#### Exemplo de necessidade 1:

Neste exemplo a seguir tentaremos usar `return`, porém quando usamos `setTimeout`, o `return` terminar o processo antes do `setTimeout`, em outras palavras o `return` irá retornar `0`, só após um [milissegundo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milissegundo) a variável estará com o valor `1`, porém `return` foi processado antes disto:

```
function test() {
   var a = 0;
   setTimeout(function() {
      //Código demorado
      a = 1;
      //Código demorado
   }, 1);
   return a;
}
console.log(test());//Irá retornar 0
```

Com callback é possível capturar a resposta de um evento "assíncrono":

```
function test(callback) {
   var a = 0;
   setTimeout(function() {
      //Código demorado
      a = 1;
      //Código demorado
      callback(a);
   }, 1);
}

test(function (response) {
    console.log(response);//Irá retornar "1"
});
```

#### Exemplo de necessidade 2:

No exemplo a seguir usei `XMLHttpRequest` assíncrono, pois ele evita congelamentos, porém tentei capturar `responseText`, mas como a resposta ainda não está pronta o resultado será uma "string vazia", `null` ou `undefined`.

```
function ajax() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'url_arquivo_grande', true);
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr.responseText;
}
console.log(ajax());//Irá retornar null ou undefined
```

Porém se usarmos `onreadystatechange`, poderemos esperar a resposta do servidor, mas não será possível usar `return`, pois ele evento está em outro ciclo/seguinto ou seja ele está assíncrono, como no exemplo:

```
function ajax() {
    var data = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'url_arquivo_grande', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
               data = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
    return data;
}
console.log(ajax());//Irá retornar null
```

Então a solução é usar callback:

```
function ajax(callback) {
    var data = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'url_arquivo_grande', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
               callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}

test(function (response) {
    console.log(response);//Irá retornar "1"
});
```

Note, só por que temos um `setTimeout`, não quer dizer que será garantia contra "travamentos", por isto segue uma lista de tecnologias desenvolvidas para tornar a experiência do usuário melhor:

- [AMD Asynchronous module definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)
- [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage)

> Note que [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) é um "servidor" assíncrono, diferente do Apache que é síncrono. A probabilidade dos servidores assíncronos terem melhor performance é muito alta e por tal motivo ele é tão "cotado".

### Diferença de assíncrona para síncrona:

Como já foi explicado anteriormente, o motivo de usar callback em especial é por causa dos eventos assíncronos, mas se não foi possível entender o que é ASSÍNCRONO, veja um exemplo de diferença entre "sincronia" e "assincronia" e o por que não podemos usar assíncrono com `return`:

[image: síncrono vs assíncrono]

O primeiro desenho (síncrono) ilustra que `a=1;` está na fila e `return a;` só será executado após `a=1;`, a desvantagem e se `a=1;` for um processo demorado, então o isto pode travar o processo principal, se não for demorado, então *sim* você pode usar síncrono.

A imagem ilustra que o `a=1;` está em um evento assíncrono (pode ser ajax, `setTimeout`, ou outros tipos), veja que `a=1;` foi só entregue após o `return a;`, portanto este retorno é executado primeiro e não traz a resposta necessária, no exemplo ele irá trazer o valor `0` ao invés de `1`, então neste caso será necessário o "callback".

Comment: por que não da para pegar o return da função se ele estiver no callback de um setTimeout?

Comment: @ropbla9 Eu editei a minha resposta.

Comment: entendi, obrigado + 1 vez

Answer (score 8):

**Javascript é single-thread**

Tanto no browser quanto fora dele (nodejs), o javascript é executado dentro de uma única linha de execução (ou Thread, em Inglês). Algumas linguagens permitem que você crie threads, mas não é o caso do javascript.

Por exemplo:

```
var a = 1;
for (var i=0; i<100000000; i++) { a++; }
```

Se esse código levar 10 segundos para executar, a execução de qualquer outra instrução no sistema será interrompida por 10 segundos.

Se no browser isso não é uma boa ideia, no lado servidor (nodejs) é pior ainda, pois nenhuma outra requisição será atendida até que termine a execução do looping acima.

**Callback para resolver o problema**

Para resolver o problema acima, foi inventado o uso de funções callback. É assim - Operações de I/O como leitura e escrita de arquivo, acesso a banco de dados ou conexões com servidores consomem muito tempo de execução, então para não travar todo o sistema nessas situações, a solução encontrada no javascript foi o uso de funções callback.

Funções callback são passadas como parâmetro e chamadas quando a operação termina. Por exemplo, no nodejs, para ler um arquivo você usa a seguinte instrução:

```
var fs = require('fs);
fs.readFile('c:\myfile.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});

console.log('teste');
```

No exemplo acima, a primeira linha tenta ler o arquivo passado como parâmetro. Como a leitura de arquivo é um processo que toma tempo (em ciclos computacionais), o controle é passado para a biblioteca de IO do node (unit 'fs'), e a execução continua para a próxima linha, onde é exibida a mensagem 'teste' na tela do console.

Quando o arquivo for lido ou um erro ocorrer (por exemplo, arquivo não encontrado), a função fs.readFile irá chamar a função callback que irá mostrar a mensagem de erro ou o conteúdo do arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 6):

## Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack?

A vantagem é poder definir um parâmetro em uma classe que é na verdade uma função. Isso isenta o programador de um framework, por exemplo, de escrever esta função, deixando isso a cargo de um programador. O framework apenas chama a função definida pelo programador sem necessariamente verificar o que essa função faz.

Apesar de vantajoso pela flexibilidade e liberdade, e a possibilidade de estender a funcionalidade de um objeto, a abordagem por callbacks é um tanto quanto permissiva, e portanto, perigosa, pois pode fazer o programador definir uma função que extrapola aspectos como segurança e responsabilidade da informação.

## O que é Thread/Multithread?

**Thread** (em português, *linha de encadeamento de execução*) [é uma forma de um processo dividir a si mesmo em duas ou mais tarefas que podem ser executadas concorrencialmente](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29).

**Multithread** é a capacidade de um processo de lidar com várias linhas de execução, [funcionalidade alegada pelo Node.js](http://jxcore.com/multithreaded-javascript-tasks/), embora a linguagem de programação JavaScript não tenha este recurso.