# Alguém poderiam me explicar porque está me retornando esse erro? (Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tenho dois models(classes)

> Classe **Membro**

```
namespace GerenciaIgreja.Models { public class Membro { public Membro() { 
DataCadastro = DateTime.Now; }

public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
public string Nome { get; set; }

[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Cpf { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Rg { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Telefone { get; set; }
public string Celular { get; set; }
public string Endereco { get; set; }
public bool Ativo { get; set; }


//[Required(ErrorMessage = "Função Ministerial é obrigatório")]
public FuncaoMinisterial FuncaoMinisterial { get; set; }
//public ICollection<Agenda1> Agenda1 { get; set; }

}
}
```

> Classe **FuncaoMinisterial**

```
public class FuncaoMinisterial { public FuncaoMinisterial() { dataCadastro = DateTime.Now; }

public DateTime dataCadastro { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Nome { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Membro> Membros { get; set; }
public bool Ativo { get; set; }
}
```

Agora preciso realizar um *insert* no banco, na tabela membros. Para isso preciso passar os atributos normais da classes *membro* mais o objeto *funcao_ministerial* que está se comportando como um atributo da classe *membro*. Para isso eu pego um id(valor) junto com meu endereço do controller(url) e passo num método `.post` do *jQuery*, para pegar o objeto *funcaoMinisterial*, o problema está aí...Pegar esse bendito objeto.

Comment: O `return response;` de `recupera_funcao_ministerial` não faz sentido, mas é melhor colocar o sitio onde essa função está a ser utilizada para ser fácil de propor uma solução alternativa.

Comment: O erro se dá na penúltima linha colada aqui, no `return` da função `recupera_funcao_ministerial`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é "meio dificil" (impossível) o `return` trabalhar com coisas assíncronas :)

Comment: Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado , vlw pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

As funções `$.ajax`, `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.getJson` são todas funções **assíncronas**, pois o Ajax é uma técnica assíncrona de requisição (sem paginação) via [*XmlHttpRequest API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), para usar Ajax é necessário callback, `return` nunca irá funcionar pois o Ajax ainda esta sendo carregado, recomendo que leia isto:

- [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635)

Depois de entender como o assincrono funciona e a necessidade do callback, vamos ajustar seu código, pode fazer algo como:

```
function recupera_funcao_ministerial(valor, url, funcionou, falhou) {

    if (url !="" && valor !="") {

        $.post(url, {Id: valor}, function (response) {
            if (response != null)
            {
                funcionou(response);
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            falhou(response);
        });

    } else {
        falhou('falta uma variavel:' + url + ' ' + valor)}
    }    
}
```

E no momento de usar deve fazer assim:

```
recupera_funcao_ministerial(1, '/minhaurl', function (response) {
    //Faz algo aqui se funcionar
}, function (erro) {
    alert(erro);
});
```

Comment: obrigado @guilhermeNascimento, quando chegar em casa hoje irei implementar, dando certo ou não eu dou um feedback.

Answer (score -4):

tenta isto e vê se ele tem as 2 variáveis...

```
function recupera_funcao_ministerial(valor, url) {

response = null;
if(url !="" && valor !=""){
$.post(url, {Id: valor}, function (response) {
    if (response != null)
    {
        return response;
    }

})}
else {
alert('falta uma variavel:' + url + ' ' + valor)}
return response;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar aqui.