# deprecation XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

gostaria se saber como faço para arrumar meu código `XMLHttpRequest`, ele está me dando essa mensagem `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.` quando tento pegar o tamanho de uma `img` em `bytes`. OBS: já tentei trocar isso: `request.open("HEAD", imgURL, false);` por: `request.open("HEAD", imgURL, true);`, porem o retorno do tamanho da `img` é 0 quando faço isso. abaixo segue a função completa de javascript

```
function getImageSizeInBytes(imgURL) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("HEAD", imgURL, false);
      request.send(null);
      var headerText = request.getAllResponseHeaders();
      var re = /Content\-Length\s*:\s*(\d+)/i;
      re.exec(headerText);
      return parseInt(RegExp.$1);
  }
```

como faço para resolver essa mensagem de `deprecation` que está retornando?

Comment: Caro Leonardo, em JavaScript usar coisas sincronas é **quase** sempre desnecessário, entendendo bem o que é um callback (RECOMENDO que leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635) você pode facilmente adaptar tudo, um exemplo assincrono de como pegar o peso do arquivo remoto: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/b68ca1a9e850f9c1962defa424986759

Comment: estou tentando utilizar como no exemplo que voce postou porem nao me retorna mais o erro, mas me retorna 0bytes no valor da img

Comment: Troque a regex por `/Content\-Length:(\s+)?(\d+)/i` e no JavaScript por `done(parseInt(RegExp.$2));`, veja se resolve.

Comment: descobri o problema porem n consegui resolver ainda, ele esta com o size certo no `console.log()` mas n estou conseguindo pega-lo para mostrar junto com o plugin dropzone.js

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento porque eu nao consigo pegar o valor do size? somente consigo mostra-lo com `console.log()` estou atribuindo em uma variavel e nao esta me retornando o valor

Comment: Caro Leonardo, porque provavelmente você ainda não entendeu como funciona o callback, veja o link do meu primeiro comentário. Tem que mover tudo para dentro da função no segundo parametro, esta tudo explicado na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635