# Como retornar true e false no addEventListener

Tags: javascript

queria saber se é possível no addEventListener como exemplo "animationend" eu inicializar uma variável como false até o fim da animação, e quando a animação terminar ela mudasse para True. Não sei como implementar isto

ou então no "mouseenter", quando o mouse estivesse sobre o elemento, a variável ficasse True, e quando fora do elemento, false.

Gostaria de ter essas variáveis para utilizar elas para disparar outras animações caso a variável correspondente fosse true!

exemplo

```
element.addEventListener('animationend', function(){
   //Código a ser executado quando a animação terminar
};

if(estado == true){ // estado que se encontra a variável que possui o valor do addEventListener
   //Código a ser executado caso o animationend tenha terminado
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar a variavel em um escopo acessível aos eventos e usar os eventos adequados, no caso de iniciar a animação é o `animationstart`, encerrar `animationend` (ou chegar ao fim)

```
var el = document.querySelector('<elemento>');
var estado = false;

animation.addEventListener('animationstart', function () {
  estado = true;
});

animation.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
  estado = false;
});
```

O mesmo vale para evento do mouse, o

```
var el = document.querySelector('<elemento>');
var estado = false;

animation.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
  estado = true;
});

animation.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
  estado = false;
});
```

Sentando true no momento que o evento é disparado.

Note que isso tudo são callbacks, ou seja se tiver algo HIPOTETICAMENTE como:

```
var el = document.querySelector('<elemento>');
var estado = false;

animation.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
  estado = true;
});

animation.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
  estado = false;
});

if (estado) {
    console.log("animado");
} else {
    console.log("NÃO animado");
}
```

**Não vai funcionar,** pois o IF já foi executado, como expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Recomendo que use a documentação do MDN (que hoje é que esta um pouco melhor que as demais) para estudar:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent