# Pegar valor de um $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma pequena função jQuery que checa qual é o último ID registrado em uma tabela do banco de dados.

Porém, preciso guardar os valor em uma variável e eu percebo que não consigo pegar o valor gerado pelo `$.get`, o máximo que consigo é um `[object Object]`.

Esta foi uma tentativa de várias;

```js
var ultimoRegistro = $.get("./core/consulta-unidades.php", function(data){      
        return data;
    });
alert(ultimoRegistro);
```

Comment: Recomendo que leia [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/3635) e [Qual a vantagem real de usar um CallBack e o que é thread/multithread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O $.get() não retorna o valor da função callback e a operação é assíncrona. Talvez seja uma chave dentro do objeto.

```
$.get("./core/consulta-unidades.php", function(data){      
    console.log(data);
});
```