# Requisição Não Respeita setTimeout no Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, setinterval, settimeout

Estou realizando uma chamada no POSTMAN na própria API que eles disponibilizam para teste. Estou fazendo a chamada do código e coloquei para depois que retornar o body, realizar mais chamadas via código para a API, segue cURL e código que estou rodando:
cURL:
`curl --location --request GET 'postman-echo.com/get'`

Rodando em Tests:

```
for(i = 0; i < tentativas; i++){
    setTimeout(() => {requestTentativas();}, 5000);
}

function requestTentativas(){
    const options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': 'postman-echo.com/get'
    }

    pm.sendRequest(options, function (error, response) { 
        try{
            console.log(response.text());
        }

        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Quando rodo o código, espero que a requisição seja feita 5 vezes no intervalo de 5 segundos, porém o que ocorre é, ele aguarda 5 segundos e depois faz todas requisições de uma única vez.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conseguem me ajudar a fazer com que o código tenha o intervalo de 5 segundos para executar cada requisição?

Comment: Acho que antes de tentar resolver o problema "no Postman", você deve se referir à [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#working_with_asynchronous_functions), que aborda exatamente o que está ocorrendo com seu código e por quê.

Comment: Substitua a linha `setTimeout(() => {requestTentativas();}, 5000);` por `setTimeout(requestTentativas, 5000 * (i+1));`. É só um contorno, o caminho mais elegante seria usando [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O `setTimeout` funciona com callbacks, "**não** é sincronizado", quando você executa loop você esta registrando um ou mais timeouts, todos quase ao mesmo tempo, então se foram "registrados" no tempo 10:20:25 (na verdade trabalha só com segundos, mas é só pra entender visualmente), todos serão executados daqui 5 segundos. Leia:

- [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635)

Note também que requisições HTTP podem ter tempos de respostas diferentes, mesmo que você chame uma primeiro, ela pode concluir somente depois, então o script não será executado na ordem, no mínimo o ideal seria esperar a requisição completar.

Ao invés de fazer um loop com for() você pode usar o próprio `setTimeout` + incremento da variável e uma `if()` para checar se terminou, exemplo:

```
let atual = 0;

const tentativas = 5;
const timeout = 5000;
const options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'postman-echo.com/get'
};

function request() {
    // Interrompe as tentativas quando atual for igual a 5
    if (atual == tentativas) return;

    // Incrementa +1
    atual++;

    pm.sendRequest(options, function (error, response) { 
        try{
            console.log(response.text());
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log(error);
        }

        setTimeout(request, timeout);
    });
}
```

Dessa forma vai esperar a requisição HTTP completar para que a próxima execute