# Usar o callback de uma função

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(function () {
$("#formulario").submit(function() {
    var cidade_nome = $('#cidade option:selected');
    var ano1 = $('#ano1').val();
    var ano2 = $('#ano2').val();
    var registro;
    var param_1;
    var resposta;
    $.post('envia.php', {cidade: cidade_nome[0].value}, function(retorno) {
    retorno = JSON.parse(retorno);
    console.log(retorno) //sai certo
    });
    //queria usar aqui
    console.log(retorno) //ele sai como undefined no console
```

Estou tentando usar o callback da função,ou seja o a variável **'retorno'** fora dela(função),procurei muito no fórum e o motivo mais falado é por ser assíncrono, entretanto não consegui chegar a uma solução.

Comment: Isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45544/3635 e isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635 devem lhe ajudar também

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O AJAX é assíncrono. Isso quer dizer que se tiveres por exemplo este código:

```
$.post('envia.php', {cidade: cidade_nome[0].value}, function(retorno) {
    // fazer algo quando o AJAX tiver sucedido
});
alert('SOpt');
```

o `alert` vai ser corrido **antes** de `function(retorno) {`. Essa função só vai ser corrida quando o AJAX receber a resposta do servidor, e a variável `retorno` só receberá o seu valor nesse momento, nesse escopo.

Uma opção é usar `async: false`, mas em 99.8% das vezes é uma má solução e uma fuga a compreender como o JavaScript funciona. 
Assim o que deves fazer é ter uma função que corra o que precisas, no escopo certo. Ou seja uma solução que faz uso de "Control flow".

Quando dizes que queres "usar a variável *retorno* fora dela (função)" eu sugiro inverteres o problema e pensares que outras variáveis precisas ter no escopo dessa função?

Uma solução é simplesmente definires essa função antes do ajax e passá-la como argumento do `$.post()`:

```
var el = document.querySelector('xpto');
function fnRetorno(retorno){
    el.innerHTML = retorno;
}
$.post('envia.php', {cidade: cidade_nome[0].value}, fnRetorno);
```

Se explicares melhor que funcionalidade te falta posso ajudar a ajustar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O método $.post é assíncrono, portanto ele será executado depois do envio do formulario, então você terá que fazer uma execução sincrona, para isto terá de usar $.ajax com async = false.

```
var onSucess= function(retorno) {
    retorno = JSON.parse(retorno);
    console.log(retorno);
};
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'envia.php',
    data: {cidade: cidade_nome[0].value},
    success: onSucess
});
```