# Usar resultado do callback numa variavel javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, funções

Eu tenho uma variável dentro do `success` da função `$.ajax()` só que preciso do conteúdo dessa variável em uma parte do código, fora do `$.ajax()`. Estou tentando criar da forma:

```
jQuery.ajax({

    url: 'http://localhost/comOferta/Api/cep',
    data: {dados:dados},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (callback){
       retorno = JSON.parse("["+callback+"]");
       var cep = retorno[0].cep;
    }
});

var enderecoPartida = cep+', Brasil';
var enderecoChegada = '08215-255, Brasil';
```

só que não está dando certo, no console dá:

> **ReferenceError:** cep is not defined

Qual forma eu consigo fazer para resgatar o resultado que está na variável `cep` ?

**Código completo**

```
 function sucesso( posicao ){

            var positions = new Array();

            positions['latitude'] = posicao.coords.latitude;
            positions['longitude'] = posicao.coords.longitude;

            initialize();

            var dados = '-23.5282792,-46.4514346';
            var cep;

            jQuery.ajax({

                url: 'http://localhost/comOferta/Api/cep',
                data: {dados:dados},
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,


                success: function (callback){

                    retorno = JSON.parse("["+callback+"]");

                    cep = retorno.cep;

                }
            });

            alert(cep);

            var enderecoPartida = '08210-791, Brasil';
            var enderecoChegada = '08215-255, Brasil';

            var request = {
                origin: enderecoPartida,
                destination: enderecoChegada,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
            });

        }

        function error(err){
            console.log(err.code);
        }


function getPosition(){

    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    if ( navigator.geolocation ){

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( sucesso , error, options);

    }
}

function mapa(){
getPosition();
}
```

Comment: Marquei como duplicada. O problema é de escopo e porque o AJAX é assíncrono. Precisas de uma callback ou de colocar esse código dentro da callback `success`. Achoq que a resposta da outra pergunta te vai ajudar.

Comment: Outra resposta parecida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50555/129

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, tentei fazer aqui mas não deu certo. Teria como me ajudar com o meu código ?

Comment: Onde queres usar `enderecoPartida`? esse código tem de estar dentro do `success`.

Comment: Eu adicionei meu código completo lá, dê uma olhada... Eu quero pegar o `callback` do `success` e jogar em uma variavel fora do `$.ajax` pois a variavel `enderecoPartida` é o CEP que terei que usar no código que está fora do `$.ajax`

Comment: Todo o código que precisar de dados que vêm por AJAX tem de estar dentro da função `success` do AJAX ou ser chamado via uma função de dentro dessa `success`. O seu `alert(cep);` tem de estar dentro do AJAX senão não vai ter os dados que queres...

Comment: Desse jeito consegui, mas acho muito ruim, pois por exemplo, tem sistemas de gráficos que será totalmente ruim para pegar dados do MySQL e inserir nas variaveis do jQuery que eles precisam

Comment: Pois, mas o AJAX é assim mesmo. Tens que adaptar o código a esse fluxo de dados. Se quiseres coloca uma pergunta em casos mais complexos a pedir ajuda a organizar o código.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado Sérgio!