# Trabalhando com o resultado de um $post com jQuery

Tags: jquery, post

fazendo um $post e obtendo o resultado json, até ai tudo ok, mais eu preciso trabalhar esse resultado fora do escopo do $post(); só que a variável após o post, fica vazia... veja o exemplo:

```
    $.post(xurl, dataToBeSent, function (data, textStatus) {
        //data contains the JSON object
        //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
        sRetFunc = data.logado;
        console.log("JSON Data: " + data.logado);
        console.log("JSON Data: " + textStatus);
        console.log("sRetFunc =  " + sRetFunc); //<-- OK

    }, "json");

    console.log("sRetFunc after =  " + sRetFunc); //<<-- aqui fica vazio
```

Qual é a forma correta de se fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Dark Ducke, marquei a tua pergunta como duplicada da outra pois acho que vais encontrar lá a resposta ao teu problema. Resumidamente tens de colocar o código que precisa de `sRetFunc` dentro da callback do `$.post`. Se tiveres duvidas ou achares que fiz errado diz. Até breve.

Comment: Outra pergunta com o mesmo problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50555/129