# Entendendo o escopo de arrow function + callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Gostaria de ter acesso ao valor de uma variável retornado de um callback fora da função callback, e também queria entender o porque que não acontece um erro de sintaxe quando tento usar uma variável que não existe dentro do escopo da função callback. Criei o exemplo abaixo para demonstrar:

```
var armazenarValor

var meuObj = {
  espera: function(valor, callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    callback(valor)
  },2000)
  }
}

meuObj.espera("valorQualquer", (valor)=>{
  armazenarValor = valor
  variavelQueNaoExiste = 'Eu não existo'
  console.log(variavelQueNaoExiste)
})

console.log(armazenarValor)
```

O valor da minha variável `armazenarValor` é `undefined`, mas gostaria que ela guardasse o valor do parâmetro `valor`, para mim utilizar em outras partes do código.

E a variável `variavelQueNaoExiste`não é declarada em nenhuma parte do código, mas mesmo assim ela funciona.

Answer (score 1):

O JavaScript não pára a execução do código por teres um `setTimeout`, ele continua a correr o código até esse `setTimeout` terminar. Se a função desse retorno direto sem ter uma parte assíncrona, aí o valor de retorno poderia ser usado, ou se a [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) fosse usada sem ser assíncronamente...

Isso quer dizer que `console.log(armazenarValor)` é corrido antes dessa [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) correr, e por isso antes do valor de armazenarValor ser mudado.

Repare neste exemplo para perceber melhor a ordem de execução:

```js
var armazenarValor

var meuObj = {
  espera: function(valor, callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
    callback(valor)
  },2000)
  }
}
console.log('antes de chamar meuObj.espera()', armazenarValor);
meuObj.espera("valorQualquer", (valor)=>{
  armazenarValor = valor
  variavelQueNaoExiste = 'Eu não existo'
  console.log('dentro de chamar meuObj.espera()', armazenarValor)
})

console.log('depois de chamar meuObj.espera()', armazenarValor)
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [Alternativas de encadeamento de funções assíncronas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140814/129)
- [Usar o callback de uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50551/usar-o-callback-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback)

Comment: Eu fiz um teste jogando tudo dentro de uma função async e utilizando o operador await para ver se seria possível ter o valor atualizado de `armazenarValor` mas mesmo assim não deu. O que eu de fato gostaria é conseguir ter acesso ao valor atualizado de `amazenarValor`sem ser somente dentro da função callback.

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa tens mesmo de usar o valor dentro da callback. Podes usar `async/await` mas nesse caso tens de ter uma promise e uma callback para o `.then` de qualquer maneira...

Comment: Juntei links de leitura à resposta para poderes ler mais sobre isso.

Comment: Eu criei esse exemplo para ilustrar a dúvida que estou tendo com a utilização de um pacote npm, o uso dele segue essa estrutura ai, como tenho que usar vários métodos e cada método depende do valor retornado do método anterior, acabarei criando uma cascata de métodos, então queria tentar escrever um código "mais limpo" evitado esse cascateamento de métodos. Em relação o uso da variável que não foi declarada em nenhuma parte do código, sabe me dizer pq isso funciona?

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa cria uma nova pergunta com o código em cascata que queres corrigir se precisares de ajuda. O primeiro link que coloquei no fim da resposta ajuda nisso. Em relação a `variavelQueNaoExiste` isso é (infelismente) possível em JavaScript. Mas se usares modo _strict_ ou boas regras de ESLint isso acusa erro.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio! O uso do `'use strict'` faz com que ele aponte erro. Vou dar uma lida nos links que você me enviou primeiramente antes de criar uma nova pergunta, obrigado pelas referências!