# Obter permissões em extensão

Tags: google-chrome-extensão

Estou a tentar obter permissões do utilizador quando um link do gmail é postado no facebook. O objetivo é partilhar o conteúdo do gmail no facebook.

```
//code from facebook
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '326350284188834',
        xfbml      : true,
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        status     : true, // check login status
        version    : 'v2.0'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id))
      return
      js = d.createElement(s); 
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "sdk.js";
      js.async = true;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


//Get current URL to share in facebook
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

    //cut permission in gmail
    chrome.permissions.request({
        permissions: ['tabs'],
        origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
    }, function(teste) {
        chrome.permissions.contains({
        permissions: ['tabs'],
        origins: ['http://www.google.com/']}, 
        function(result) {
            if (result) {
                var teste="pede permissão1";
                console.log(teste);
            } else {
                var teste="não pede permissão1";
                console.log(teste);
            }
        });

        if (teste=="pede permissão") {
            console.log('permissão pedida'); 
        } else {
            console.log('permissão não pedida');
            document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.url;
            document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.data;
            console.log(tab.data);
            document.querySelector("div.fb-share-button").setAttribute("data-href", tab.url);
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3-ak.buzzfed.com/static/css/webfonts.css?v=1370354313" type="text/css" />-->
        <script src="fbbutton.js"></script>
       <!-- <script src="settings.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="sdk.js"></script>-->
        <style>
          div span, iframe {
            height:50px!important;
            width:100px!important;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:160px; height:200px; font: normal 21px/23px 'ProximaNovaSemibold',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <form id="share" action="" method="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="share2" name="share" /> <span style="position:relative; top:3px;margin-bottom:20px;c">Quer partilhar no face?</span>
                </label>
               <div id= "share1"class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" style="width:100px; height:50px;"></div>
            </form>          
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "teste-gmail",
  "description": "This extension will share the contents of your gmail.",
  "version": "1.0",


  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title":"Gmail",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

"permissions": [
    "http://mail.google.com/*",
    "http://google.com/",
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://mail.google.com/*",
    "https://www.facebook.com/",
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "optional_permissions": [ "tabs", "http://mail.google.com/*",  "http://google.com/"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, info, tab){  
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);     
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "fbbutton.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: O código não pede as permissões ao utilizador para ser postado no facebook o conteúdo de cada email.

Comment: @Marta por que você está usando o snippet para formatar o código?

Comment: Outra coisa @Marta seu código tá com várias falhas de "indentação" e tem alguns que eu vejo que você copiou, mas você "modificou" sem necessidade alguma, deixando falhas no código. Vou lhe fazer uma pergunta, você já programou alguma vez, fora este código? Não fique chateada com o meu comentário por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É como eu disse nas suas duas outras questões Marta, você deve ler a documentação e ter certeza que está usando o exemplo da maneira que está lá. Neste caso (permissões) o link é este: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions

O código original é assim (conforme documentado):

```
chrome.permissions.request({
  permissions: ['tabs'],
  origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
}, function(granted) {
  // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
  if (granted) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
});
```

Mas você fez isto, modificou totalmente o código:

```
chrome.permissions.onAdded.addListener({permissions: ['tabs'], origins: ['http://www.google.com/']});
```

Para resolver o problema você tem que entender o que são "callbacks", uma boa resposta aqui aqui no próprio [StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/3635).

Para resumir o código deve ser algo como (modifique dentro da `if(granted)` conforme a necessidade):

```
chrome.permissions.request({
    permissions: ['tabs'],
    origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
}, function(granted) {
  if (granted) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.url;
    document.getElementById('share2').innerHTML = tab.data;
    document.querySelector("div.fb-share-button").setAttribute("data-href", tab.url);
  }
});
```

[Documentação completa](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions)

Comment: @Marta sobre não receber os dados, poderia dizer qual email você está tentando? Vou tentar reproduzir o problema

Comment: É o Gmail. Posso postar todo o código aqui caso seja necessário.

Comment: Neste caso acho que dá para abrir uma exceção (mesmo que descaracterize a pergunta), edite a sua questão e poste o html e o js. Eu aguardo.