# Pegar items com prefixos da array

Tags: php, array

Eu possuo uma `array` assim: `array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'my_one' => 55, 'my_two' => 33)`.

Mas eu gostaria de pegar apenas os dados que começassem com `my_*`. Existe alguma forma mais elegante, ou terei que rodar a `array`, pegar os primeiros 3 caracteres, e comparar com `my_`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma das diversas abordagens que pode ser usada para isto, é usar a função [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-grep.php) para retornar os itens que combinam com um padrão, e para fazer isso, indique as chaves da *array* com a função [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php):

```
$numeros = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'my_one' => 55, 'my_two' => 33);
$myNumeros = preg_grep('/^my_.*/', array_keys($numeros));

print_r($myNumeros); // [3] => my_one [4] => my_two
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](http://ideone.com/4B6dp6)

Uma outra forma de fazer isto, é usar a função [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para filtrar as chaves da *array* usando a função `array_keys`, e no [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/6454), comparar o valor com [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) (ou [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stripos.php) para *case-insensitive*):

```
$numeros = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'my_one' => 55, 'my_two' => 33);

$myNumeros = array_filter(array_keys($numeros), function ($chave){
    return (strpos($chave, 'my_') !== false);
    });

print_r($myNumeros); // [3] => my_one [4] => my_two
```

[Ver **`demonstração`**](http://ideone.com/EyvYkE)

Comment: Editei a expressão regular pois a pergunta requer `my_*`, e não `my*`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra abordagem seria esta:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'my_one' => 55, 'my_two' => 33);
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(strripos($key, 'my_') === 0){
            echo $key.'<br />'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Percorrer todos os itens e verificar se a primeira posição da chave começa com `my_` usando strpos.