# recuperar dados de arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estou precisando implementar uma tradução em um plugin chamado de pikaday, que é na verdade um datepicker, e como o site é multilinguagem estou tentando implentar o i18n. puxando as traduções de um JSON:
https://myjson.com/1bazm

e aqui no jsfiddle o exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/pz4pwkLq/1/

qual a melhor maneira de pegar cada tradução por vez? por exemplo, e se eu quiser pegar o valor "pt-br" e passar para uma variável? como seria?

Comment: Você pode definir a linguagem como path, hashbang ou search de uma URL. Cada vez que ela (URL) é carregada, você invoca a função que renderiza o calendário com a respectiva entrada do idioma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso de quereres ir buscar os textos traduzidos tens de usar AJAX. Podes também fazer isso no servidor, mas assumindo que fazes com JavaScript podes usar o [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Nota que AJAX (`$.getJSON`) é assincrono, então tens de colocar o código que precisa desses textos dentro da [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) do `$.getJSON`.

Assim, um exemplo, usando `"en-us"`:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1bazm', function (i18n) {
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: $datePicker,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        i18n: i18n.langs["en-us"]
    })
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pz4pwkLq/2/

Comment: Coloquei a versão em PT: http://jsfiddle.net/pz4pwkLq/3/

Comment: Também é possível fazer isso direto, sem api:
http://jsfiddle.net/pz4pwkLq/4/

Comment: opa, desculpe a demora em responder, mas era isso mesmo @Sergio