# Consulta em arquivo Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estou a fazer uma listagem de cidades e estados via `JSON`. Sempre crio uma tabela no banco para retorno destas informações. Mais hoje estou a fazer direto ao arquivo `JSON`.
O layout do arquivo estados:

```
[{"ID": "1",
"Nome": "Afonso Cláudio",
"Estado": "8"
},
 {
"ID": "2",
"Nome": "Água Doce do Norte",
"Estado": "8"
},
 {
"ID": "3",
"Nome": "Águia Branca",
"Estado": "8"
},
 {
"ID": "4",
"Nome": "Alegre",
"Estado": "8"
}, etc]
```

O que preciso e não estou conseguindo, e retornar todas as cidades que tenham o mesmo valor da chave `Estado`.

A consulta eu realizo da seguinte forma:

```
$.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/json/Cidades.json", {'Estado':2}, function(json) {
  var options = "<select name='cidade' id='cidade' class='form-control show-tick'>";
  $.each(json, function(key, value){
   options += '<option value="' + value.Sigla + '">' + value.Nome + '</option>';
  });
  options += '</select>';
  $("#selectCidades").html(options);            
});
```

Então da maneira que está a filtragem não acontece com a chave `ID` informada.
Obs: o valor 2 do parâmetro informado e somente de exemplo, este valor vem de uma variável preenchida pelo `select` estados

Comment: Possível duplicata de [recuperar dados de arquivo JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89791/recuperar-dados-de-arquivo-json)

Comment: @RORSCHACH Está marcação da pergunta da possível duplicata não resolve o meu problema, até já fiz da forma descrita na reposta da mesma e não funciona.

Comment: Qual é a linguagem que tens no servidor? PHP + MySQL?

Comment: @Sergio Sim. E que tenho que salvava somente as cidades cadastradas no banco, então u não queria criar mais 2 tabelas para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Se fizeres a filtragem no servidor é melhor, até porque já passas a informação de que `Estado` procuras. Mas podes fazer isso no cliente, usando `.filter()`, assim:

```
json = json.filter(obj => obj.Estado == 2)
```

Um exemplo seria:

```js
const estado = 2;
$.getJSON("<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/json/Cidades.json", {'Estado': estado}, function(json) {
    const html = json.filter(obj => obj.Estado == estado).reduce((select, obj) => {
    return select + '<option value="' + value.Sigla + '">' + value.Nome + '</option>';
  }, "<select name='cidade' id='cidade' class='form-control show-tick'>") + "</select>";

  $("#selectCidades").html(html);
});
```

Comment: Então. Quando eu tiver no pc eu irei tentar implementar. Desconhecia o filter do JSON. Mais acredito que terei que fazer várias alterações aí.