# Ajuda com o mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Não entendendo oq ta acontecedo:

```
ready = function() {
  groups = mongoose.model('groups', schemas.group);
  groups.find({}, function(err, docs){
    for(i in docs){
      console.log(docs[i].name);
    }
    return docs;
  });
}

console.log(ready());
```

SAIDA:

```
undefined
Grupo A
Grupo B
Grupo C
```

dentro da função ready() ele traz tudo normalmente, mas no "console.log(ready())" ele imprime "undefined"

não era pra ele imprimir como na função?
se alguem poder me ajuda eu agradeço

Comment: Pessoal decobri o problema. oque ta acontecendo é que a função "ready" retorna antes que a callback "groups.find()" seja chamada. alguem tem alguma sugestão do q posso fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: Explica o que queres fazer para podermos dar um exemplo concreto. Tens um proplema de assíncronismo, muito commun no Node. O que queres fazer com esse ready? queres ter uma variável que te diga se  a query já foi feita?

Comment: isso. A ready tem a função de ler todos os registros do banco e retorna-los

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebo do teu código o método `.find()` é assincrono. Então tens de usar uma callback para receber esses resultados. A lógica pode ser assim:

```
var ready = function(callback) {
  groups = mongoose.model('groups', schemas.group);
  groups.find({}, callback);
}
```

e depois chamas a função `ready` passando como argumento a função que vai ser chamada quando os dados estiverem prontos:

```
ready(function(err, docs){
    for(i in docs){
      console.log(docs[i].name);
    }
    // fazer algo com os dados aqui...
});
```

Ou seja, não podes usar a lógica sequêncial habitual do JavaScript sincrono, mas sim uma lógica de callback. Podes ler mais sobre isso aqui [(link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129).

Comment: isso mesmo, problema resolvido, obg Sergio me ajudou bastante