# Como fazer elementos aparecerem e sumirem com Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho, por exemplo 3 títulos. Quero que quando o site carregue, um apareça, depois ele desapareça e apareça o outro, depois o segundo desapareça e apareça o terceiro.

Podem usar como código o seguinte:

```
<div>
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 1</h1>
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 2</h1>
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso ta parecendo "faça para mim", poderia mostrar o que ja tentou?

Comment: Não tentei nada por que não sei como faz :/ Acho que seja algo como fazer em js para ele aparecer depois de um segundo, durar um segundo a aparecer o outro.

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar um [mcve]. Assim fica mais fácil da gente simular seu problema em algo já feito por você. :)

Comment: A pergunta é específica (descreve bem o que deseja), é relevante para outros (por ter aplicação ampla) e está no contexto no SO. Nesse caso, não sei por que "faça pra mim" torna essa uma pergunta ruim. O _exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável_ se aplica a perguntas sobre um problema no código, não a perguntas que sequer têm código.

Comment: @rodorgas É justamente por não ter código nenhum que fica duvidoso a intenção. Se ele ainda não sabe nem sequer por onde começar, o melhor que ele pode fazer é estudar e não pedir o código pronto :)

Answer (score 6):

você tambem pode fazer este efeito apenas com CSS.

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
}
div h1 {  
  animation-name: exibirOutros;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

div h1:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
div h1:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 2s; }
div h1:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 4s; }
div h1:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 6s; }

div h1:nth-child(1) { animation-name: exibirInicial; }
div h1:nth-last-child(1) { animation-name: exibirFinal;}

@keyframes exibirInicial {
  0% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
  75% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
  100% { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes exibirOutros {
  0% { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }
  25% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
  75% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
  100% { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes exibirFinal {
  0% { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }
  25% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
  100% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 1</h1>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 2</h1>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 3</h1>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 4</h1>
</div>
```

Pode parecer redudante setar o `visibility` e o `opacity` no `@keyframes`... porém um elemento com `visibility: hidden` não pode ser clicado, enquanto um com `opacity: 0` pode... por um outro lado, não é possivel aplicar um efeito de transição (a.k.a fade-in/fade-out) com o `visibility`, porém é possivel com o `opacity`.

No exemplo acima é desejavel o efeito de `fade` e que não dispare um evento ao clicar em um `<h1>` invisivel.

Comment: Ótimo, mas quero que ele faça isso uma vez, e pare no ultimo, tem como?

Comment: @Júlio, realizei uma alteração no script.

Comment: CSS fazendo alteração com base no tempo? Caramba, é quase inacreditavel hehe

Comment: Tem como usar transition fazendo deste modo?

Comment: @Júlio, você pode definir as demais regras da sua animação dentro do `@keyframes`

Comment: Quero que ele desapareça, dê uma pausa, e apareça o outro com uma transição como ease-in-out do css3, já tentei de todos os jeitos e não deu. Uso transition no elemento ou uso animation no keyframes?

Comment: Júlio, no caso de `animations`, você pode setar `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out`, em todo caso também será preciso setar os seus `key-frames` com o css desejado para cada momento... você pode olhar o exemplo atualizado.

Answer (score 4):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var toggle = function(){
    jQuery('#event_toggle').children().hide();                //  ESCONDE TODOS ELEMENTOS FILHOS
    var current = jQuery('#event_toggle').find('.current');   //  PEGA O ELEMENTO COM CLASS "current" (ATUAL)
    if(!current.length){                                      //  CASO NÃO HAJA UM (PRIMEIRA ITERACAO) PEGA O PRIMEIRO FILHO
      current = jQuery('#event_toggle').children().first();   //  PEGA O PRIMEIRO FILHO ".first()" MANTEM NO OBJETO JQUERY
    }
    current.show();                                           //  EXIBE O ELEMENTO ATUAL

    if(current[0] == jQuery('#event_toggle').children().last()[0]){   //  SE ELEMENTO ATUAL = O ULTIMO ENTAO APENAS GERA 
      setTimeout(function(){                                          //  UMA NOVA ITERACAO PARA ESCONDE
        current.hide();
      },1000)
    }else{                                //  ELEMENTO ATUAL NÃO É O ULTIMO
      if(current.hasClass('current')){    //  SE TIVER A CLASS "current" (NÃO É A PRIMEIRA ITERAÇÃO)
        current.removeClass('current');   //  REMOVE ELA PARA PASSAR AO PROXIMO
      }
      current.next().addClass('current'); //  PASSA A CLASS "current" PARA O PROXIMO ELEMENTO
      setTimeout(toggle, 1000)            //  CHAMA NOVAMENTE A ITERAÇÃO APOS 1s
    }
  };

  setTimeout(toggle, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event_toggle">
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 1</h1>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 2</h1>
  <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 3</h1>
</div>
```

#### Recomendações de estudo

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)
[callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/14213)

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples de fazer isso é assim:

```
<div id="el">
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 1</h1>
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 2</h1>
    <h1>TEXTO DE EXEMPLO 3</h1>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('el'),
      total = el.children.length, t = 1000, count=0;
     setInterval(function() {
        for (var j=0; j < total; j++) {
            el.children[j].removeAttribute("class");
        }
            el.children[count].setAttribute("class", "active");
            count++;
         if (count == total) {
            count=0;
         }
   }, t);
})();
```

para interromper no último:

```
(function(){
  var el = document.getElementById('el'), total = el.children.length, t = 1000, count=0;
     var interval = setInterval(function() {
        for (var j=0; j < total; j++) {
            el.children[j].removeAttribute("class");
        }
            el.children[count].setAttribute("class", "active");
            count++;
         if (count == total) {
            clearInterval(interval);
         }
   }, t);
})();
```

**Css:**

```
#el h1 {
  display:none;
}
#el h1.active {
  display:block;
}
```

## Exemplo contínuo em jsfiddle.




## Exemplo interrompido em jsfiddle.

Comment: Tem como ele parar quando aparecer o ultimo?

Comment: Veja na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.2.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#bt").click(function(){

$("p").hide();
})

$("#bt1").click(function(){

$("p").show();
})

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Texo:
<button id="bt"> hide</button>
<button id="bt1">show</button>

<p>
<select id="select" name="marcas" >
<option value="bmw">BMW</option>
<option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
<option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente isso que ele queria, ele queria por item, e não todos os   títulos sumissem e aparecessem de uma única vez. Também se certifique de dar uma explicação mínima do que o seu código faz, por mais simples que seja.