# Em NodeJS, variável global no meu arquivo app.js está indefinida em outro arquivo

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou em um projeto utilizando NodeJS, e seu framework Express.

No arquivo principal *app.js* eu chamo uma função com o objetivo de ler um arquivo, e atribuo a uma variável global:

```
global.google_sheet_credentials = readFileCredentials("spread_sheet.txt");
```

O código da função *readFileCredencials* é:

```
readFileCredentials = function(file){
    fs.readFile('data-source/credentials/'+file, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Could not open file: %s", err);
        }else{
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }
    });
};

module.exports = readFileCredentials;
```

Após isso, eu redireciono para outro arquivo:

```
rek('dashboards/ti/main_it');
```

Neste arquivo *main_it.js*, eu tento utilizar essa variável global *google_sheet_credentials*:

```
console.log(google_sheet_credentials);
```

porém avisa que ela está indefinida, alguém pode me explicar o motivo, e uma forma para que eu consiga o resultado certo?

Comment: Você pode criar um modulo para ler o `.txt` e importar ele no arquivo que você deseja.

Comment: Esse `readFileCredentials` é síncrono?

Comment: Ele é uma função que recebe o nome do arquivo, e retorna o conteudo desse arquivo, não sei lhe dizer se é sincrono ou assincrono.

Comment: Podes colocar o código dessa função aqui?

Comment: Coloquei o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa função é assíncrona, ou seja esse `return` não é usado da maneira que pensas.

Tens de usar uma [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) (ou via Promise como foi sugerido noutra resposta). Assim, só podes contar com o valor setado nesse `global.google_sheet_credentials` quando a [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) for chamada.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```
readFileCredentials = function(file, cb){
    var _path = 'data-source/credentials/' + file;
    fs.readFile(_path, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Could not open file: %s", err);
        }
        cb(err, data); 
    });
};

module.exports = readFileCredentials;
```

e depois usares assim:

```
readFileCredentials("spread_sheet.txt", function(err, data){
    global.google_sheet_credentials = data;
    // agora a variável está setada. Se precisares de correr outro código tens de o ter aqui dentro, ou chamando funções a partir daqui
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não funciono. Eu criei um repositório no git, e importei a parte que está dando o problema, para ficar melhor de visualizar: https://bitbucket.org/JGonczoroski/teste . Quando puder dar uma olhada

Comment: @JonathanGonczoroski onde estás a precisar de `google_sheet_credentials`? não vejo isso no teu código

Comment: No arquivo que se encontra: `dashboards/implantation/pushers/teste.js` , la encontra-se um print dessa variável

Comment: @JonathanGonczoroski porque não usas a lógica normal de fazer requires nos ficheiros em vêz de estares a usar o espaço global? Isso foi uma das grandes novidades e vantagens do Node.js...

Comment: Pois é, eu peguei um projeto nessa estrutura, e devo modificá-lo, porém eu comecei aprender agora NodeJs, portanto segui a estrutura que ja estava. Quanto a sua dica, você está dizendo que ao invés de eu tentar colocar o conteúdo do arquivo em uma variável global, eu devo usar um require?! Mas qual arquivo devo importar em qualquer lugar?

Comment: @JonathanGonczoroski pois, acho que devias usar a maneira comum no Node. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/mootools/website/blob/master/build/docs.js é do site do MooTools onde eu participo. A ideia é fazer require de todos os módulos que precisas em um dado ficheiro. Todos os requires à cabeça, para organizar código e o Node faz com que cada require fique em memória e só seja carregado uma vez.

Comment: Então você tem esse Docs.js que importa os módulos que você quer usar no projeto. Porém, quando quer usar algum desses módulos ja importados, importa o Docs.js? Eu não achei nenhum .js importanto o Docs.js para poder utilizá-los

Comment: @JonathanGonczoroski não. Cada ficheiro importa o que precisa. Nalguns casos faço require de exatamente a mesma coisa em ficheiros diferentes. A regra é fazer require dos ficheiros/modulos que esse ficheiro precisa.

Comment: Entendi, no meu caso, eu não precisaria utilizar o `require('fs)` nesse arquivo `app.js`, pois só utilizo manipulação com arquivos no arquivo `readFileError` certo? Porém isso me ajuda no meu problema de conseguir a informação do arquivo antes de dar indefinido ?

Answer (score 3):

Claramente o problema do seu código é com assincronismo. Promises podem resolver o seu problema:

```
function readFileCredentials(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile('data-source/credentials/' + file, 'utf8', function(err, data){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Could not open file: %s", err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = readFileCredentials;
```

Na chamada, basta usar o **then** para dar continuidade no processo da Promise:

```
readFileCredentials("spread_sheet.txt").then(function(googleSheetCredentials) {
    global.google_sheet_credentials = googleSheetCredentials;
});
```

### Atualização:

Conforme o link que foi passado, tente modificar o seu código App para funcionar da seguinte maneira:

```
var App = (function(){

    // Method Construct, your objetive is loading modules and utils that will be used in this project.
    function App() {
        this.define_global_utils(function() {
          this.define_global_modules();
        }.bind(this));

        this.init();
    }

    // Method responsible for initiating the application.
    App.prototype.init = function(){
        this.load_modules();
    };

    // Method responsible for importing the modules used in this project.
    // The modules were imported globally, that is, can be used in anywhere in the code.
    App.prototype.define_global_modules = function() {
        global.rek = require('rekuire');
        global.fs = require('fs');
    };

    // Method responsible for imported the utilities.
    App.prototype.define_global_utils = function(callback){
        global.readFileCredentials = rek('data-source/utils/readFileCredentials');

        readFileCredentials("spread_sheet.txt", function(err, data){
            global.google_sheet_credentials = data;
            callback();
            // agora a variável está setada. Se precisares de correr outro código tens de o ter aqui dentro, ou chamando funções a partir daqui
        });
    };

    // Method responsible for loading the dashboards.
    App.prototype.load_modules = function(){
        rek('dashboards/implantation/main_implantation');
    };

    return App;
})();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não funciono. Eu criei um repositório no git, e importei a parte que está dando o problema, para ficar melhor de visualizar: https://bitbucket.org/JGonczoroski/teste . Quando puder dar uma olhada. O código está com a solução do Sérgio, porém eu também testei a sua, e também não deu certo. Provavelmente é algo relacionado ao meu código, se puder me ajudar agradeço