# $.GET JQuery Dùvida

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

*Tenho o  método:*

```
RepoApi.prototype.getContributors = function() {
    var returnList = [];
    $.get(this.url).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        returnList = response;
    }).fail(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

    return returnList;
};
```

Porque o `$.get` assíncrono está sempre retornando a lista vazia?
Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de mudar a lógica dos argumentos desse método. Uma vez que ele é assíncrono tens de usar [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) (ou Promise) para correres código quando ele tiver uma resposta para te dar. O que acontece é que o JavaScript liberta o processo `$.get` e antes de esperar pela resposta continua a correr a linha seguinte que é o `return returnList;`. Essa linha é portanto corrida **antes** de o `$.get` ter sido recebido, daí que a tua variável nunca é setada.

Sugiro algo assim:

```
RepoApi.prototype.getContributors = function(callback) {
    $.get(this.url).done(function(response) {
        callback(null, response);
    }).fail(function(response){
        callback(true, response);
    });
};
```

e depois quando usares seria algo assim:

```
RepoApi.getContributors(function(err, res){
    if (err) return console.log('Houve um erro!');
    // a partir daqui podes usar a array "res" dentro desta função 
    // ou funções chamadas por esta
});
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração no meu método getContributors. mas o erro persiste. vou editar para você ver como estou tentando acessar o método.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto não mudes a pergunta. Cria um jsFiddle para vermos o código

Comment: cara já editei.. vou mas vou criar o jsFiddle

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto o problema é que todo o código tem de estar dentro dessa callback, o `console.log` e o `for` seguinte.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto viste o meu comentário? O código deve ficar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/xb9z1xcg/

Comment: Valeu, funcionou :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu fortemente lhe recomendo que não trabalhe de forma síncrona com o AJAX. Requisições síncronas estão obsoletas e isso faz bastante sentido, em uma linguagem **Single-Thread**, sofrendo concorrência com renderizações de **HTML** e **CSS** no navegador, o uso de requisições síncronas tendem a ser uma má prática (não vejo um caso que seja visto como uma boa ideia, talvez alguém saiba, mas até hoje eu NUNCA vi).

Você pode adequar o seu código para funcionar de maneira assíncrona facilmente:

```
RepoApi.prototype.getContributors = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: this.url
  });
};
```

Agora basta usar corretamente o método no local onde ele é chamado, por exemplo:

```
var repo = new RepoApi();
repo.getContributors()
  .done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).fail(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Trabalhar com o AJAX de forma assíncrona é a maneira ideal, mas se estiver insatisfeito da maneira que tem que se trabalhar com assincronismo (usando **Promises**), você tem outras duas opções:

- Estude mais a fundo: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (o que o jQuery implementa nesse caso com os métodos #done #fail, apesar de não seguir interface definida pela ECMA) e [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators), então de uma olhada na ideia do [task.js](http://taskjs.org/). Várias bibliotecas possuem mecanismos para se trabalhar com essa ideia, o próprio [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) possui uma função (**Q.spawn**) para a mesma ideia do **task.js**.
- Estude por [async-await](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/async-functions.html), uma feature do ES7 que resolve todos esses problemas de uma maneira simples e elegante. Existem alguns pré-processadores que permitem o uso do **async-await**, que inclusive pode ser solucionado com a ideia do **task.js**.