# Retornar Valor setInterval

Tags: javascript

Como é que consigo retornar um valor de um setInterval ?

```
result = setInterval(function () {
   var cont = i++;
   return cont;
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de usar uma lógica assíncrona com [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129).

Quando fazes

```
var result = setInterval(function () {
   var cont = i++;
   return cont;
}, 800);
```

a variável result guarda uma instância do próprio setInterval para poders parar ou cancelar. Mas para saberes o valor de `cont`, ou melhor para o usar em código tens de chamar uma outra função passando-lhe o valor que `cont` tem na altura que o setInterval é corrido. Ou seja, encadear o código para o próximo passo ser chamado no momento que o `setInterval`  está a correr a sua função.

Então terá de ser algo como:

```
function proximaFuncao(contagem){
    // aqui podes usar a variável "contagem" que irá ter o valor que "cont" tem no momento que esta função é invocada
}

var result = setInterval(function () {
   var cont = i++;
   proximaFuncao(cont);
}, 800);
```

Comment: Eu só não percebo bem para que é o i neste contexto, não está especificado na pergunta. Se o objectivo for só o contador o i nem precisa de lá estar. Não nos foi explicado para que era

Comment: @Miguel pois, eu tb não, mas não mudei para só mudar o que tem a ver com a lógica assíncrona. Mas acho que o problema é o assincronismo.

Comment: Yap. boa solução aí

Answer (score 3):

A função [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) retorna um id do intervalo (usado para posteriormente cancelar esse intervalo), logo você não deve usar `return`.

Você pode se valer de escopos porém conforme resposta do Pedro Luzio. Adicionalmente você pode utilizar uma [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) para delimitar o escopo das variáveis.

```
var cont=0; // visivel em escopo "global"
(function(){
    var i=0; // visivel somente dentro do bloco
    setInterval(function () {
        cont = i++;
    }, 800);
})();

// alert(cont) funciona
/// alert(i) undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Terás de declarar a variável cont como variáverl global, pois o valor que a função retoma é o ID do intervalo...

```js
i=0;
var cont=0;
setInterval(function () {
   cont = i++;
}, 800);
```