# Aguardar valor da variável para retornar função

Tags: javascript, funções, return, base64

Estou tentando criar uma função que transforme um arquivo em uma URL de Dados.
Mas estou enfrentando um problema: O valor do retorno da função não é o esperado por mim.
Segue o meu código:

```js
File.prototype.toData = function() {
  
  //Leitor de Arquivos
  var leitor = new FileReader();
  var dados  = false; //Não há dados inicialmente
  
  //Quando o leitor ler o arquivo
  leitor.onload = function(e){
    dados = e.target.result; //Grava a string de dados na variável
  };
  
  //Inicia a leitura deste arquivo
  leitor.readAsDataURL(this);

  //Minha Tentativa:
  //while(!dados){}
  
  //Retorna os dados
  return dados;

}


function teste(i) {
  console.log('Dados: '+i.files[0].toData())
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onchange='teste(this)' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu problema é que esse método é assíncrono e não podes fazer somente `var foo = i.files[0].toData();`

Tens de usar uma [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) para te dar a string quando ela estiver pronta. Assim pode exemplo:

```
File.prototype.toData = function(cb) {
    // Leitor de Arquivos
    var leitor = new FileReader();

    // Quando o leitor ler o arquivo
    leitor.onload = function(e) {
        cb(e.target.result); // Envia a string de dados quando esta estiver pronta
    };

    // Inicia a leitura deste arquivo
    leitor.readAsDataURL(this);
}

function teste(i) {
    i.files[0].toData(function(dados) {
        console.log('Dados: ' + dados);
    });
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/LynLm3jj/

Desse modo passa uma função a `File.prototype.toData = function(cb) {` e quando o `onload` fôr chamado ele invoca essa função passando os dados que queres:

```
leitor.onload = function(e) {
    cb(e.target.result); // Envia a string de dados quando esta estiver pronta
};
```