# Pegar valor de dentro de uma função

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, http-request

tô com um problema de lógica aqui, acho q deve ser uma coisa bem "burra" de minha parte, tipo, tenho que tirar um valor de dentro da função, e não estou conseguindo com um return por ser um request http. olhem:

```
$scope.postData = function(method, data, file){

    var uploadUrl = base_url+'main/upload/';

    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file.file, uploadUrl, file.title);

    $http.get(base_url+'main/lastId/')
    .success(function (data) {
        lastId = data;
        return lastId; // <------ PRECISO DESSA VARIÁVEL
    });

    data.last_id = lastId; // <----- PARA USAR ELA AQUI

    $http.post(base_url+method+'/post/'+table, data)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.exibirForm = 'listar';
        $scope.form = {};
        $scope.estadoBotao = "Adicionar";
    });
}
```

como viram, preciso pegar o lastId, para modificar o array data para fazer uma postagem com uma ligação do id de um arquivo.

Comment: Tem que fazer um callback conforme as respostas abaixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) do AngularJS é assíncrono, portanto a variável será indefinida nesse momento.

Uma opção é usá-la no `success`, algo asssim:

```
$http.get(base_url + 'main/lastId/')
    .success(function(data) {
        lastId = data;
        facaAlgo(lastId); // irá passar o valor para a função
    });


function facaAlgo(lastId) {

    data.last_id = lastId; // Aqui poderá usar lastId, porquê terá sido resolvido pela Promise

    $http.post(base_url + method + '/post/' + table, data)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
            $scope.exibirForm = 'listar';
            $scope.form = {};
            $scope.estadoBotao = "Adicionar";
        });
}
```

O que acontece é que você está tentando usar um valor que ainda não existe, porque o `http` não irá travar a execução, ele irá ser executado e passar para a próxima instrução. O nome para resolver esse tipo de situação é [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback).

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou. Me ajudou entender. Essa parte de o $http.get ser assíncrono tava me atrapalhando muito, pq n sabia disso kk.

Comment: Cara, surgiu outro problema q n tinha reparado antes... a função fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(); também tem um http.post. e é desse post q quero pegar o lastId, ai por isso tá pegando um id anterior do último. E como fiz um ele como um service, como faço p obedecer um promise?

Comment: Dependendo da forma da sua implementação você pode retornar a Promise e resolver ela em outro lugar @ViníciusVilela. Se ainda está com esse problema recomendo fazer outra pergunta com os detalhes :)

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer um CALLBACK, passando o parâmetro para um novo método, pois quando chegar o resultado do AJAX, a função/método provavelmente já foi executado.

Segue abaixo um exemplo (não testei):

```
$scope.postData = function(method, data, file){
    var uploadUrl = base_url+'main/upload/';
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file.file, uploadUrl, file.title);
    $http.get(base_url+'main/lastId/')
    .success(function (data) {
        pegaRetorno(data); // <------ PRECISO DESSA VARIÁVEL
    });
}

function pegaRetorno(lastId){
    console.log(lastId);
    data.last_id = lastId; // <----- PARA USAR ELA AQUI  
    $http.post(base_url+method+'/post/'+table, data)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.exibirForm = 'listar';
        $scope.form = {};
        $scope.estadoBotao = "Adicionar";
    });
    return valor;
}
```