# Variável não tem o seu valor após done ou fail no ajax

Tags: jquery

Criei uma função para retorna `true` ou `false` quando o ajax. No inicio da função declarei um variável "r" para receber `true` em caso se sucesso ou `false` em caso de falha, porém a váriavel não tem o seu valor modificado. e acaba retornando o valor que foi atribuído no inicio `false`. O que há de errado?

```
function loadSkeleton(r) {
    var r;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/sys/ajax/publicacao.xhtml"
    }).done(function (answer) {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/post.css">');
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/aside-publication.css">');
        $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/other-publi.js"></script>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.side-left').html($(answer).find('content').html());
        }, 2000);
        r = true;
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $('.side-left').html('<p>Failed request</p>');
        r = false;
    });
    return r;
}
```

O `.done` está funcionando por que as mudanças no DOM são visíveis.

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite. O que está ocorrendo é que a função que você criou está retornando imediatamente o valor de `r`, e os métodos `.done` e `.fail` são `assíncronos`, ou seja, recebem como parâmetro funções (neste caso, você está duas funções anônimas) que são invocadas **posteriormente** (quando a requisição é completada com sucesso ou quando ocorre um erro).

Para tentar adaptar sua função para o objetivo que você quer (receber true ou false, dependendo do sucesso da requisição), você pode enviar uma função como argumento e invocá-la quando necessário. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function loadSkeleton(fnOK) {
    $.ajax({
        /* ... */
    }).done(function (answer) {
        /* ... */
        fnOK(true);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        /* ... */
        fnOK(false);
    });
}

/* 
    Quando você for chamar a função loadSkeleton, passe como argumento
    uma função (neste caso aqui, uma função anônima)
*/

loadSkeleton(function(ok) {

    /*
        O parâmetro será true, ou false, 
        dependendo de como ela for invocada lá no loadSkeleton.
    */
    console.log(ok); 

});

/* 
   Ou declare sua função - callback antes e passe como argumento 
   Obs.: sem os parêntese, apenas a referência - parênteses iria invocá-la, 
   que não é o que queremos

*/

var fnOK = function(ok) {
    console.log(ok); 
};

loadSkeleton(fnOK);
```

Sugiro a leitura [desta resposta aqui no SOPt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/49387) sobre **callbacks** e [este capítulo](https://github.com/braziljs/eloquente-javascript/blob/master/chapters/05-funcoes-de-ordem-superior.md) sobre **Funções de Ordem Superior / *High Order Functions***