# $.getJSON - Como armazenar responseJSON em uma Variável?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou montando um Objeto em Javascript com o seguinte constructor:

```
var jsonResult = ""; // Inciei uma variável fora do escopo da Função

function criarDicionario(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    this.dicio = $.getJSON('pt-br.json').done(function(data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON); /* O Alert exibe corretamente o responseJSON */
        jsonResult = data.responseJSON;
    });

    console.log(this.dicio); // Devolve Objeto
    console.log(jsonResult); // Devolve Undefined
    /* Gostaria de armazenar this.dicio.responseJSON em uma variável */

    this.renderMessage = function(text) {
        document.write(this.dicio.responseJSON['text']);
    }
}
```

O que eu gostaria é que a variável `this.dicio.responseJSON` pudesse ser armazenada de tal forma que eu pudesse chamá-la posteriormente na função `renderMessege()`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é callback?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%c3%a9-callback)

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` é [assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback), portanto o valor retornado por ele será `undefined` na próxima linha, e também o responseJSON estará dentro de dicio. Sugiro você efetuar as próxmas operações dentro do *callback*  done, algo mais ou menos como:

```
function criarDicionario(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    $.getJSON('pt-br.json').done(function(data) {
        this.dicio.responseJSON = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(this.dicio.responseJSON);
    });

    this.renderMessage = function(text) {
        document.write(this.dicio.responseJSON['text']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu conseguiria chamar o renderMessage de dentro do `.done`?

Comment: Na minha opinião você poderia deixar o `renderMessage` fora da function `criarDicionario`..o que acha?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso va funcionar

```
function criarDicionario(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    var dicio;
    $.getJSON('pt-br.json').done(function(data){
        dicio = data.responseJSON;
        alert(data.responseJSON); /* O Alert exibe corretamente o responseJSON */
    });

    console.log(dicio); // Devolve Objeto (aqui ja vai ser o objeto de responseJSON)
    /* Gostaria de armazenar this.dicio.responseJSON em uma variável */

    this.renderMessage = function(text) {
        document.write(dicio['text']);
    }
}
```

Resumindo o que acontece é que a variavel `dicio` estava guardando o objeto que faz a requisicao e nao a resposta da requisicao, por que ajax é asincrono.

Por isso estou setando a variavel `dicio` no `done` que é a funcao que é executada quando a requisicao finalizar.

Outro probleminha é o `this` basicamente ele aponta para a propria funcao, ou seja vai procurar por uma variavel chamada `dicio` dentro da funcao `renderMessage()` como voce havia declarado `dicio` dentro de `criarDicionario()` ela nao existia no escopo de `renderMessage()`. Note que eu tirei o `this` da var `dicio`.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode te ajudar, eu reconstrui a sua função e acho ela bem arriscada.

Mas enfim, aqui está:

```
            var jsonResult;

            function criarDicionario(lang){
              this.lang = lang;
              this.dicio = $.getJSON("maicon.php").done(function(data) {
                    jsonResult = data;
                });
            }

             criarDicionario("pt-br");
```

Neste exemplo estou te entregando a mostra do que fiz... Espero ter ajudado!!