# Como faço para retornar o valor de uma query no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id` = 1', function(err, row) {

    var jogo = row[0].jogo;


    console.log(jogo);


    });
```

O problema é, se eu tirar o var jogo da função, ele já não funciona, contudo precisava que ele saisse da função para fazer umas outras verificações fora da função.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema aqui é assincronísmo. Tens de usar [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) para invocar uma função quando esse valor tiver sido retornado da base de dados.

Se tens lógica que precisa dele tens de encadear as coisas por exemplo assim:

```js
function verificarJogo(jogo) {
  // aqui podes fazer as verificações que precisas
  console.log(jogo);
}

function buscaJogo(id) {
  var select = 'SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id` = ' + id;
  pool.query(select, function(err, row) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    verificarJogo(row[0].jogo);
  });
}

buscaJogo(1);
```

Ou fazer ao estilo de promises:

```js
function verificarJogo(jogo) {
  // aqui podes fazer as verificações que precisas
  console.log(jogo);
}

function buscaJogo(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
    var select = 'SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id` = ' + id;
    pool.query(select, function(err, row) {
      if (err) rejeitar(err);
      else resolver(row[0].jogo);
    });
  });

}

buscaJogo(1).then(verificarJogo);
```