# Comportamento inesperado no javascript assíncrono

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo

Estou escrevendo um código backend usando javascript, node e os módulos npm 'mysql' e 'request'. Tentei escrever um módulo para fazer um pooling de conecções da base de dados SQL por diferentes chamadas de API em variados arquivos do meu projeto. Meu módulo mysqlLib.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host : settings.host_DB,
    user : settings.user_DB,
    password : settings.senha_DB,
    database : settings.DB
});

module.exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if(err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    callback(err, conn);
    conn.release();
  });
};
```

Ao terminar este módulo eu decidi testar com um arquivo tester.js

```
var mysql = require('./lib/mysqlLib.js');
var request = require('request');

mysql.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    conn.query(query1, function(err) {
        conn.query(query2, function(err) {
            request.get(url1, function(err, httpResponse, body){
                conn.query(query3);
            });     
        });
    });
});
```

De fato, o código realizou o que eu queria que ele fizesse: Toda vez que precisar fazer alterações na minha base de dados por meio de algum middleware na API que escrevi em qualquer dos meus arquivos, usar o método getConnection de mysqlLib.js para puxar uma conecção da minha pool e ao término do uso liberá-la de volta para a pool. O que está me incomodando é que notei algo que devia estar levando esse pequeno programa a um erro e não está... Vejam, a função 'conn.query(query, callback)' é assíncrona, isso quer dizer que ela não interrompe o fluxo do código. Desse modo, pensei que ao realizar a primeira invocação de 'conn.query' em tester.js, essa função iria ser executada de maneira assíncrona permitindo que a callback do getConnection chegasse ao fim. Isso não deveria significar que o programa terminaria o callback e daria release() na conecção que foi puxada? Pensei que conseguiria chamar a primeira conn.query mas uma vez que callback chegasse a seu final e a connecção fosse liberada não conseguiria realizar as demais queries aninhadas à primeira pela falta dela mas elas estão todas sendo executadas sem erro! Me pergunto o que pode possivelmente estar acontecendo, por que a conecção é liberada somente após o término de todas as callbacks aninhadas no callback de getConnection?

Comment: Tenho pouca experiência em node.js, mas vou arriscar um palpite: pode ser que a função `conn.release()` possua uma verificação para evitar o fechamento de conexões que estão sendo utilizadas em consultas, desta forma o código pára no `release` e só continua quando o callback de `conn.query()` retorna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa biblioteca permite configurar o numero máximo de ligações quando estás a usar `pool`. Se não especificares um valor [o máximo é `10` conforme a documentação](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options):

> **connectionLimit**: The maximum number of connections to create at once. (**Default**: 10)

Para além disso, apesar do código ser assíncrono, o browser lê as funções sincronamente. Ou seja quando lê a primeira `conn.query(...`, ele abre uma ligação e só a termina quando a função retornar. Não o retorno assíncrono via callback, mas quando tiver lido todo o código dentro da função. Ora antes que isso aconteça o `mysql` não vai fechar a ligação a não ser que haja um `.end()` específico no código.

Assim, antes de a primeira função dar `return` ele abre as aninhadas, portanto a ultima a ser chamada é a primeira a ser fechada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Sergio, se isso acontece no browser provavel que aconteça também no servidor certo?

Comment: @MatheusBafutto esse teu código é _server-side_,  a minha resposta é sobre código que roda no servidor (Node.js) uma vez que MySQL é server-side

Comment: sim sim, perdão pelo mal entendido... Você tem algum link de referência que explica esse comportamento para javascript (seja uma seção na documentação ou algo do tipo)? Só para consultas futuras mesmo.

Comment: @MatheusBafutto vai perguntando aqui se tiveres mais duvidas, sobre callbacks podes ler aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129, e há outras perguntas com respostas que ajudam muito também. Até breve!