# Callbacks que não entram na minha mente!

Tags: javascript, node.js, funções, callback

Galera estou tentando pegar bem o conceito de `callbacks` antes de começar estudar `NODEJS`.

Porem eu não consigo de fato entender a sintaxe de callbacks... é apenas passar uma função por parâmetro?

```
função1 (parametro?){
     retorno da função
    }
    função2(parametro?,função1){
    ...
    }
```

Isso é considerado um `callback`? desculpa ser tão leigo parece que ta faltando alguém desenhar kkk.

Comment: Olha, para mim callback é o retorno de uma função. Se uma função retorna algo, ela tem callback, se não, ela não tem.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback

Comment: Eu vi todo aquele POST mas não consigo realmente entender...

Comment: @Nicoletti estava a preparar uma resposta aqui, mas acabei por juntá-la à outra resposta que já tinha dado. É uma resposta nova basicamente, por isso sugiro que dês uma olhada lá: [O que é callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129)