# Retorno de query em variável Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo

Estou fazendo um código no node.js que acessa banco de dados SQL Server. Criei uma variável que armazena o resultado de uma query, o problema é que não consigo acessar essa variável fora do método de conexão ao banco. Segue o código:

```
var lexml = 'xml';

sql.connect(config).then(() => {
  return sql.query`SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 
  CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 
  XML_SIG)),'') AS XML_NF  FROM SPED050
WHERE DOC_ID = 36220; `;
}).then(result => {
  lexml = result.recordset[0].XML_NF.toString();
  console.log(lexml); // <---------------Aqui é apresentado o xml normalmente
  return lexml;
}).catch(err => {
    console.dir('Erro na consulta');
})
sql.on('error', err => {
   console.dir('Erro ao acessar o banco'); 
});

console.log(lexml); // <------ Aqui é impresso apenas "xml"
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? como posso acessar a variável "lexml" com o resultado da query fora do método de conexão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque node.js é assíncrono, portanto ele não aguarda o resultado entre uma instrução e outra (em caso de métodos assíncronos). O que você pode fazer é quando cair no *callback* chamar uma função para dar continuidade, algo assim:

```
[...]
.then(result => {
  lexml = result.recordset[0].XML_NF.toString();
  exibirXml(lexml)
})
[...]
function exibirXml(xml){
  console.log(xml);
}
```

Comment: Entendi. Deu certinho, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

Esse `sql.query` retorna uma promisse que na sua [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) disponibiliza `result`.

Só no momento em que essa [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) é chamada é que tens acesso à variável, e portanto todo o código que precise dela **tem de ser chamado a partir do interior dessa [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129)**.

Se por exemplo tiveres uma função `next` que precise desse valor tens de chamar de dentro dessa callback, assim:

```js
sql.connect(config).then(() => {
  return sql.query `
      SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), XML_SIG)),'') AS XML_NF
      FROM SPED050
      WHERE DOC_ID = 36220;
  `;
}).then(result => {
  const lexml = result.recordset[0].XML_NF.toString();
  next(lexml); // <--------------- aqui dás continuação ao fluxo do programa
}).catch(err => {
  console.dir('Erro na consulta');
})
sql.on('error', err => {
  console.dir('Erro ao acessar o banco');
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!