# Funções executam fora de ordem

Tags: javascript

Eu estou chamando uma requisição via função, para carregar 2 itens diferentes para minha tela.

Nessa função eu passo como parâmetro a categoria que ele pertence, para ser carregado.

```
function requisicao(categoria){

var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    values = {"modulo":modulo,"categoria":categoria};
    myJsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = respond;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "classes/getData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);



    function respond() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa');
            x[0].innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    }
}
```

Acontece que a categoria 6 (garantia de update), tem que aparecer primeiro que a 9(Suporte e consultoria), porém, está acontecendo, as vezes acontece de a categoria 9(Suporte e consultoria) carregar primeiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A garantia de update tem que aparecer primeiro.

```
requisicao(6);


requisicao(9);
```

Eu pensei em colocar um "sleep" entre essas funções porém o sleep não está funcionando.

O que fazer?

**Atualização**

```
function requisicao(categoria, callback){
    //seu código...
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    values = {"modulo":modulo,"categoria":categoria};
    myJsonString = JSON.stringify(values);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = respond;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "classes/getData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);
    //como o código executado na volta da requisição é a função respond, chamamos o callback aqui
    function respond() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa');
            x[0].innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        //verifica se uma função foi de fato passada, para então chama-la
        if(callback){
            callback.call();
        }
    }
}


function pegaSuporte(){
    requisicao(9);
}

requisicao(6, pegaSuporte);
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque essas funções são assíncronas. Isso significa que a resposta de cada uma das requisições voltará quando o servidor conseguir responder, e isso não segue a ordem do pedido.

Para resolver isso, você pode passar um callback para a função `requisição`, e chama-la no final da função `respond` :

```
function requisicao(categoria, callback){ 
    //seu código...

    //como o código executado na volta da requisição é a função respond, chamamos o callback aqui
    function respond() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            x = document.getElementsByClassName('terceiraEtapa');
            x[0].innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        //verifica se uma função foi de fato passada, para então chama-la
        if(callback){
            callback.call();
        }
    }
}
```

E você pode criar uma função para pegar a requisição de suporte:

```
function pegaSuporte(){
   requisicao(9);
}
```

E assim, passa-la no callback:

```
requisicao(6, pegaSuporte);
```

Dessa maneira, ele buscará a outra categoria apenas quando trouxer a primeira do servidor.

Você pode ler mais sobre callbacks e assincronia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback).

Comment: O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Suas chamadas para a função `requisicao` esperam que ela se comporte de forma síncrona, mas requisições http são assíncronas, e não tem como saber em que ordem elas voltarão do servidor

Comment: Olha na atualização

Comment: Criei o código que tu falou

Comment: Você implementou o callback na função, mas não tá usando ele em lugar nenhum. Olha no final da minha resposta, chame a requisição 9 no callback da requisição 6

Comment: Calma ae, vou postar o resto do código

Comment: Pronto, olha ai o codigo com todas as chamadas

Comment: Você tem certeza que agora tá chamando a função somente no `requisicao(6, pegaSuporte);` ?

Comment: sim, ta exatamente dessa forma

Comment: E o que está acontecendo de errado? Ainda tá colocando o suporte primeiro?

Comment: js-proposta-comercial.js:15 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

Esse erro

Comment: Linha 15 = 
    xmlhttp.send(myJsonString);

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66215/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-artur-o-templario).