# Por que é necessário criar uma função para executar certos métodos?

Tags: javascript, funções, função-anônima

```
.onclick = function() {myFunction()};
```

Por quê o exemplo abaixo não dá certo?

```
.onclick = myFunction()
```

Ele executa sem eu ter clicado!

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>
```

Comment: O primeiro exemplo poderia ser apenas `.onclick = myFunction` e, assim, ficaria bem fácil perceber a diferença.

Comment: Você tem que criar um id para o seu input, afinal está mandando a sua função capturar pelo ID "demo" entende

Answer (score 12):

No primeiro caso,

```
.onclick = function() {myFunction()};
```

Você está atribuindo ao evento `onclick` a definição de uma função. Neste caso, uma função anônima que, quando executada, chamará a função `myFunction`. Ou seja, o valor de `onclick` será uma função anônima.

Já no segundo caso,

```
.onclick = myFunction()
```

Você está chamando a função `myFunction` e o retorno dela será atribuído ao `onclick`. Por isso que sua função sempre é chamada antes do *click*. Como a função `myFunction` não possui retorno, o valor de `onclick` será nulo, `undefined`, e nada será executado quando o elemento for pressionado.

Para entender melhor a diferença, você pode melhorar o primeiro código fazendo:

```
.onclick = myFunction
```

Assim, você define que o valor de `onclick` será a própria função `myFunction` e, portanto, quando o elemento for pressionado, a função será executada. Veja melhor a diferença:

```
.onclick = myFunction    // Não executa a função, apenas no click
.onclick = myFunction()  // Executa a função e atribui o retorno, não executa no click
```

Criar uma função anônima para chamar a função desejada, como foi feito no primeiro exemplo da pergunta, só é interessante quando esta função possui parâmetros definidos diferentes do próprio evento. Todos os eventos do JavaScript, por padrão, passam como parâmetro para a função de *callback* um objeto que representa o evento a ser tratado. Se sua função possui um parâmetro diferente, você deve criar a função anônima, ou algo equivalente:

```
function myFunction(message) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message;
}

.onclick = function (event) {
  myFunction("YOU CLICKED ME!");
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Por que você precisa criar um número ou uma *string* ou um *array*, ou ainda qualquer outro objeto? Por que o problema pede aquilo, certo? É a mesma coisa. Você tem um problema que exige uma função, então tem que criá-la.

Neste caso específico você tem uma propriedade de um objeto que é um evento, ou seja, quando algo acontecer com o objeto ele deve executar algo. Como dizer para ela o que deve ser executado? Você cria uma função com o que deve ser executado e informa qual é essa função para a propriedade, assim como você faz com qualquer outro valor. A função é só um valor. O valor dela é o código a ser executado.

A sintaxe

```
.onclick = myFunction()
```

Está chamando a função  `myFunction()` e colocando o resultado dela em `.onclick`, não é o que deseja, não quer o resultado da função, você quer a própria função.

Já a sintaxe

```
.onclick = function() {myFunction()};
```

Não chama a função, ela apenas declara a função e a própria função é que é guardada em `.onclick`. No caso esta função anônima (note que ela não tem um nome) apenas chama `myFunction()`.

Esta técnica é chamada de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), ou seja, você está dizendo o que deve ser chamado de volta em determinado momento.

A sintaxe diferente define se você está chamando ou criando uma função. A declaração de função sempre começa com a palavra reservada `function` e sempre tem um corpo, pode ou não ter um nome.

Isto:

```
function nome() {}
```

é o mesmo que isto:

```
nome = function() {}
```

Uma forma simplificada de fazer o mesmo:

```
.onclick = myFunction
```

Note que a sintaxe aqui não é uma chamada de função porque não inclui os parenteses. Então está passando apenas o nome de uma função já existente em vez de chamar a função. Então pense assim:

```
nome = function() {};
.onclick = nome;
```

Olha só está declarando uma função e está guardando ela em uma variável. Aí você está pegando o valor desta variável, que é uma função, e está atribuindo para a propriedade `.onclick`. É o mesmo que fazer:

```
function nome() {}
.onclick = nome;
```

Mas isto é um pouco diferente:

```
function nome() {}
.onclick = function() {nome()};
```

C[oloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/Events.js).

Porque aqui tem duas funções uma que chama a outra.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade funciona veja o exemplo abaixo, o que acontece é que quando você seta

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = myFunction();
```

o navegador entende que esta é a função de controle do event click por isso seria necessário colocar outra function, para que esta seja a function de controle não a sua.

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function(){myFunction()};
```

para resolver este problema você precisa retirar os "()" para que seja interpretado como não parâmetro, mas sim como um call action:

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = myFunction;
```

```js
function myFunction(){
  alert("foi");
}

document.getElementById("demo").onclick = myFunction;
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="click-me" id="demo">
```