# Callback como retorno de argumento

Tags: javascript, funções, callback

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, pelo que eu entendi `callbacks` são funções passadas como parâmetro que serão executadas quando alguma instrução for realizada, mas eu vejo com frequência o `callback` como palavra reservada para retornar parâmetros a uma função, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
function run(textQuery, callback)
{
    const sql = require('mssql');
    var callbackDone = false;    
    const connectionPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, err => {   
        connectionPool.request()
        .query(textQuery, (err, result) => {            
            sql.close();
            callbackDone = true;
            callback(err, result);
        })    
    })    
    connectionPool.on('error', err => {        
        sql.close();
        if(!callbackDone)
        {
            callback(err, null);
        }
    })
}
```

Poderiam me explicar como isso funciona ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback) pergunta abrange muito sobre o conceito de *callback*. A diferença ao que pontuou é que pode-se passar o *callback* como parâmetro da função quando a *função de retorno* precisa de **parâmetros adicionais** (na maioria das vezes um valor faltante). Vou ilustrar:

```
function handler(err, res, message){
    // message é o parametro que estava faltando
    console.log(err, res, message);
}

function run(textQuery, callback){
    callback(null, [], "Success");
}

run("", handler);
```

Comment: Utilizando seu exemplo, se eu bem entendi, a palavra 'callback', nesse caso, esta sendo utilizada para completar a solicitação de parâmetros exigidos pela função handler que foi passada como parâmetro a função run?

Comment: Na verdade está passando qual é a função de callback, é uma referência @B.Dias

Comment: Nossa, entendi, agora que ficou mais claro esta até bem óbvio kk, Obrigado pela Ajuda @Lucas Costa