# Timers no Node.js: as suas diferenças e a sua relação com process.nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

Qual a diferença entre `setInterval`, `setTimeout` e `setImmediate` no Node.js?

Sei que `setTimeout` cria um único temporizador, como um *delay*, e o `setInterval` cria um intervalo. Mas e o `setImmediate`?

Além disso, há uma relação entre esses temporizadores e o [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args)?

Answer (score 1):

[Segundo a documentação](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/):

`setTimeout()` pode ser usado para agendar a execução de código após uma quantidade designada de milissegundos. Essa função é semelhante à `window.setTimeout()` da API JavaScript do navegador, no entanto, uma cadeia de código não pode ser passada para ser executada.

`setImmediate()` executará o código no final do ciclo do ciclo de eventos atual. Esse código será executado após qualquer operação de E/S no loop de eventos atual e antes de quaisquer cronômetros programados para o próximo loop de eventos. Essa execução de código pode ser pensada como ocorrendo "logo após", significando que qualquer código após a chamada de função `setImmediate()` será executado antes do argumento da função `setImmediate()`.

Se houver um bloco de código que deve ser executado várias vezes, `setInterval()` pode ser usado para executar esse código. `setInterval()` recebe um argumento de função que será executado um número infinito de vezes com um atraso de milissegundos dado como o segundo argumento. Assim como `setTimeout()`, argumentos adicionais podem ser adicionados além do atraso, e estes serão passados ​​para a chamada de função.

De uma olhada [nesse video](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=0ahUKEwj6v7XPk87aAhVLHZAKHadBA2QQwqsBCCcwAA&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov) do rodrigo branas sobre timers do node.js

Answer (score 1):

Vou acrescentar alguns pontos em relação a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293227/95771), principalmente sobre `setImmediate` e o `process.nextTick`.

Se executarmos o seguinte código no Node.js teremos o seguinte:

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick'))
setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate'))
```

Saida:

```
nextTick     // primeiro
setImmediate // segundo
```

Apesar de `setImmediate` ter uma proposta bem similar ao `process.nextTick` (adiar a execução de uma função), semanticamente estes são diferentes. Funções de [*callbacks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback/27182#27182) cuja as chamadas foram adiadas pelo `process.nextTick` são chamadas de **microtask** e estas são executadas imediatamente após a atual operação completar, antes mesmo de qualquer outro evento de E/S que seja disparado. Por outro lado, `setImmediate` tem sua execução adicionada à fila de eventos, e esta será executada somente após todos os eventos de E/S terem sido processados.

Pode parecer confuso, mas se formos fazer uma análise lógica, esses nomes deveriam ser trocados, pois `process.nextTick` dispara **imediatamente**, antes de um `setImmediate`. Mas como isso é um conceito que está enraizado desde o nascimento do Node.js, acho difícil que seja alterado.

Uma vez que `process.nextTick` é executado antes de qualquer operação de E/S agendada, ela será executada mais rápida, mais cedo. Porém, tenham em mente que esta poderá atrasar qualquer operação de E/S pendente, ou em casos mais extremos, pode gerar um loop longo/infinito através de uma função recursiva, por exemplo, e acabar causando o **[I/O Starvation](https://github.com/nodejs/promise-use-cases/issues/25)**. Isso não acontece com o `setImmediate` como já explicado na outra resposta.

Antes de finalizar, vou deixar claro que `setImmediate` tem prioridade e sempre será executado antes de qualquer temporizador **se programado dentro de um ciclo de E/S**, independentemente de quantos temporizadores estão presentes, e que `process.nextTick` tem prioridade sobre `setImmediate`.

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log('nextTick'))
setImmediate(() => console.log('setImmediate'))
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout'), 0)
const interval = setInterval(() => console.log('setInterval'), 0)
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(interval), 0)
```

Saída:

```
nextTick
setImmediate
setTimeout
setInterval
```

---

#### Curiosidade `setImmediate` e `setTimeout`

A ordem em que os temporizadores são executados varia dependendo do contexto em que são chamados, ou seja, a ordem não é determinística. Se ambos forem chamados de dentro de um simples script, o tempo será limitado pelo desempenho do processo (que pode ser afetado por outros aplicativos em execução na máquina)

Por exemplo, se executarmos o seguinte script que não está dentro de um ciclo de E/S , a ordem em que os dois temporizadores são executados não é determinística, variando de máquina para máquina, pois está vinculada ao desempenho das mesmas:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout')
}, 0)

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('immediate')
})
```

No entanto, se você mover as duas chamadas dentro de um ciclo de E/S, o retorno de `setImmediate` será sempre executado primeiro:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs'

readFile('text.txt', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout')
  }, 0)
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate')
  })
})
```