# load desabilita funções jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

estou dando um load() na minha div, porem ele sempre desabilita comandos jquery assim que ele da load! Alguma solução???

```
   $(document).ready(function () {  

$('#form_campo').on('submit', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'matriz/salvacad.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#form_campo').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        $('.erase').click();

$(".menu").load(location.href + " .menu > *");

        }

    });

    return false;
    });
```

a função do jquery em um outro arquivo é

```
    $('.cat').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       $('.categoria').fadeToggle("fast");
       $('.menu').fadeOut('slow');
});
    $(".close_red").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $(".categoria").fadeOut('fast');


                          });
```

mas so funciona antes do reload, ou dando um refresh na pagina

```
<div class="menu" id="menu">
            <div class="menux cat">Categoria</div><br>
            <div class="separated"></div>
            <?php
               mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$mostra = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria" )or die (mysql_error());
$ver = mysql_fetch_array($mostra);


$status = $ver["categoria"];

if (empty($status)){

 echo('');

}
    else{

    echo('<div class="menux camp" style="margin-top: 10px; ">Campos do Produto</div><br>
    <div class="separated"></div>   ');

    }       
            ?>

            <div class="menux prod" style="margin-top: 10px; ">Produtos</div><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Você quer carregar uma url (http://localhost.menu. > *) dentro da classe menu?

Comment: @RicardoPontual o resultado nao vem do $_POST, é so o result que aparece numa consulta sql, vou editar pra tu ver

Comment: @adventistaam isso mesmo, vem de um localhost,

Comment: Tentou usar um append?

Comment: deu certo a ajuda do @RicardoPontual, porem meu form desabilitou o submit depois do load tbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom usando a dica do @Ricardo Portugal, mudamos o query depois que ela retorna e deixamos assim!

```
    $('.menu').on('click','.cat', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       $('.categoria').fadeToggle("fast");
       $('.menu').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

usamos o comando .on() que ele ativa as alterações e o uso da query, qto ao formulario, ele deu redundancia com um outro form dentro dele, então removi!

Por enquanto resolvido!!

Answer (score 0):

**possível Solução um:**

Adicionar o código no [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%c3%a9-callback) do *load*

```
$(".menu").load(location.href + " .menu > *", function(){

    $('.cat').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.categoria').fadeToggle("fast");
        $('.menu').fadeOut('slow');
    });

    $(".close_red").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".categoria").fadeOut('fast');
    );
});
```

**Possível solução dois:**

Usando o `jQuery(document.body)` mesmo com o `load` de uma nova parte, ele sempre irá ler o documento todo

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.cat', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.categoria').fadeToggle("fast");
    $('.menu').fadeOut('slow');
});


jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.close_red', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".categoria").fadeOut('fast');
});
```

<sub>Digo "possível" porque já houve um caso que um não funcionou, porém o outro sim</sub>