# Callbacks em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

Gostaria de entender uma coisa sobre callbacks! Sei que existe outros tópicos sobre o assunto, mas o meu é uma dúvida simples e que não está clara pra mim ainda.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que tenho esse array:

```
['Banana', 'Maçã', 'Melancia']
```

Pra percorrer o mesmo eu vou usar o forEach com uma função e vou exibir com `console.log`

```js
const minhaArray = ['Banana', 'Maçã', 'Melancia'];

function impri(nome, indice){
  console.log(`${indice + 1}. ${nome}`);
}

minhaArray.forEach(impri);
```

O callback no caso, é somente a função `impri` ou o callback é tudo em conjunto? A função impri junto da array e do forEach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Callback* ou *Callback function* é a função que é passada a outra função, e que irá ser chamada mais tarde, quando necessário.

[Confirme a definição de *Callback function* no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Callback_function)

Por isso no seu exemplo, o callback é a função `impri`, pois é ela que é passada ao `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

O [conceito de callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129) é mais habitual em casos assíncronos. É possível dizer que `impri` é a callback, se bem que o conceito em si é mais comum em processos assíncronos, porque é a função que é passada como argumento e vai ser chamada de volta.

Neste caso, para responder à tua pergunta: `impri` é a callback, a função em si e não o conjunto onde ela é usada.