# Funcionamento do Array.filter() no Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá! Estou tentando gerar um vetor com apenas um "resultado". Basicamente faço uma query no mongo que me retorna todos os atendimentos realizados.

Quero gerar um array contendo apenas os atendimentos já finalizados, que no banco estão armazenados como status = 'F'. Vou usar esse array para gerar um gráfico.

Na minha view abri uma tag script e coloquei o seguinte:

```
 var teste = [];

    teste.filter(function (){
        if(status == 'F'){

        }
    });
```

E é aí que vem minha dúvida, nessa function() eu tenho que passar um objeto? (No caso esse objeto seria a coleção do mongo ou algo assim eu imagino). E aí se o status for F, eu adiciono no array, se não, não.

É mais ou menos assim que funciona o filter ou estou enganado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) recebe um [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback), ou seja, uma função que recebe como um dos argumentos os elementos contidos no `array`.

Pelo que entendi você tem um `array[{}]` de objetos, conforme representando na variável `dados`.

## Na prática:

```js
let dados = [{
        'id': 1,
        'status': 'F'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'status': 'M'
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'status': 'F'
    }
]


let novoArray = dados.filter(finalizados);

console.log(novoArray);

function finalizados(value) {
    return value.status === 'F';
}
```

Comment: É, imagino que seja por aí mesmo. Esse finalizados seria o array gerado após o filtro?

Comment: @danibrum finalizado é o método que filtra pelo `status='F'`

Comment: Ah entendi, vou ver se consigo fazer funcionar com os dados do banco aqui, muito obrigado!

Comment: @danibrum dá uma olhadinha na documentação, não tem segredo :)