# Como trabalhar com filter em um array typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Vou preferir mostra primeiro a mensagem de erro que está dando.

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
> signature. Type '((...items: any[]) => number) | ((...items:
> RacaEspecificoTipo[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.

Essa mensagem aparece logo quando subo a aplicação Angular. Eu vou preferir mostrar primeiro o código de como estava antes e depois como mostrar a minha tentativa e logo em seguida dizer o meu objetivo da minha modificação.

Esses são os dados vindo do banco de dados:

> 0: {id: 1, descricao: "Linguado", tipo: "Glkpo", tipo: "Peixes"} 1:
> {id: 2, descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"}
> 2: {id: 3,…} 3: {id: 4, descricao: "Morcegos", tipo: "GENERICO",…} 4:
> {id: 5, descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO",…} 5: {id: 6,
> descricao: "Cães", tipo: "GENERICO", tipoAnimal: "Mamiferos"} 6: {id:
> 7,…} 7: {id: 8, descricao: "Posta", tipo: "Glkpo",…} 8: {id: 9,
> descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"} 9: {id:
> 10, descricao: "Lobos", tipoAnimal: "Mamiferos"} 10: {id: 11,
> descricao: "Outros", tipo: "OUTROS", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"}

Essa é a entidade em questão:

```
export class RacaEspecificaTipo {
  id: number;
  descricao: string;
  tipo: RascsEspecificoTipoEnum;
  tipoAnimal: string;
}
```

Essa é a implementação antes da modificação:

```
loadTiposRacas(): void {
        this.eventSubmitStart.emit();
        this.service.getTiposRacas()
          .pipe(catchError(this.handleErrorAndContinue([])))
          .subscribe(tiposRacas => {
            this.tiposRacas = tiposRacas;
            this.eventSubmitDone.emit(false);
          });
        }
```

Meu objetivo é colocar um filtro na lista de tal maneira que ele liste somente registros que cujo **tipoAnimal** seja somente **Peixes**, não tive sucesso por falta de habilidade com typescript, eu não sei como ele trabalha com Arrays, quando eu fiz essa mofificação como pode ver abaixo ele gerar o erro como foi mostrado no início dessa postagem.
**Esse código abaixo foi minha tentativa em filtrar os registros.**

```
  loadTiposRacas(): void {
    this.eventSubmitStart.emit();
    this.service.getTiposRacas()
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleErrorAndContinue([])))
      .subscribe(tiposRacas => {
        this.tipoRacas.filter(value =>  { 
            value.tipoAnimal === "Peixes"
            
            tiposRacas.push(value);
           
            
        }); 
        this.eventSubmitDone.emit(false);      
    });   
  }
```

A variável tipoRacas está sendo iníciada através dessa variável abaixo:

> tipoRacas : RacaEspecificoTipo[] = [];

Por favor que modificação eu poderia realizar no meu código que pudesse corrigir o erro?
O resultado esperado deveria ser esse abaixo;

> 0: {id: 1, descricao: "Linguado", tipo: "Glkpo", tipo: "Peixes"} 1:
> {id: 2, descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"}
> 2: {id: 3,…} 3: {id: 5, descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO",…} 4:
> {id: 7,…} 5: {id: 8, descricao: "Posta", tipo: "Glkpo",…} 6: {id: 9,
> descricao: "Escamas", tipo: "GENERICO", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"} 7: {id:
> 11, descricao: "Outros", tipo: "OUTROS", tipoAnimal: "Peixes"}

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Funcionamento do Array.filter() no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319011/funcionamento-do-array-filter-no-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você errou é confundir a variável criado para mostrar a informação no seu componente com aquela que retorna um resultado da sua requisição API, ou seja, `this.tipoRacas` é a variável do componente e `tipoRacas` é o resultado da requisição, então é por `tipoRacas` que deve ser aplicada o filtro e por fim passar o valor para `this.tipoRacas`, exemplo:

```
loadTiposRacas(): void {
    this.eventSubmitStart.emit();
    this.service.getTiposRacas()
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleErrorAndContinue([])))
      .subscribe(tiposRacas => {
        this.tipoRacas = 
            tipoRacas.filter(value => 
                value.tipoAnimal === "Peixes"
            ); 
        this.eventSubmitDone.emit(false);      
    });   
}
```

a diferença é sutil:  `this.tipoRacas = tipoRacas.filter`, ou seja, `this.tipoRacas` recebe o valor filtrado de `tipoRacas`, eu faria mais uma modificação não colocando nome igual e variáveis que possui funcionalidades diferentes no código.

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Funcionamento do Array.filter() no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319011/funcionamento-do-array-filter-no-javascript)
- [How to filter an array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916135/how-to-filter-an-array-in-javascript)
- [javascript filter array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594788/javascript-filter-array-of-objects/13594818)
- [How to filter array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827040/how-to-filter-array-of-objects-in-javascript/50827078)