# O que acontece com a memória RAM se uma tecla for pressionada no computador por muito tempo?

Tags: memória, teclado, stack

O que acontece com a memória RAM se uma tecla for pressionada no computador por muito tempo? Exemplo: computador foi ligado e uma tecla fica pressionada esses bytes estão sendo lidos pelo processador e escrito na memória, certo?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Me lembrou de um bug em software que usava que obrigava um "enter" para seguir uma paginação , muitas vezes deixei um grampeador pressionando a tecla.

Answer (score 15):

Depende do que estiver rodando:

- pode ser que ocorra nada
- pode ser que ocorra o mínimo e fique fazendo isso sem ocupar memória porque o acionamento provoca algo momentâneo apenas
- pode ser que vá ocupando 1 byte cada vez que ela tem um acionamento, o que levaria anos para estourar a memória típica de um computador, em considerando a memória virtual poderá levar séculos, hipoteticamente
- pode ser que uma única tecla estoure a memória porque ela aciona ações que fazem um monte de coisa. Ou seja, o "computador" não faz nada em específico, depende do programa que está rodando decidir o que fazer com este acionamento

Se o computador só foi ligado e nem tem um sistema operacional, acontecerá nada. Se tiver um Windows e mais nada também deve acontecer nada importante, o Windows processará cada acionamento e descartará em seguida, em um editor de texto poderá estourar a memória, mas pode ter proteções contra isto. O código que está rodando é que determinará o que fazer.

O acionamento da tecla criará o que se chama interrupção no processador e isto fará com que uma execução de código será desviada para uma rotina previamente determinada por algum código, quase certo que será o sistema operacional que determinou qual é esse código (é uma forma de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101)), pelo menos será assim em computadores PC normais em condições apropriadas.

O sistema operacional determinará o que fazer com esta tecla. Ele pode fazer algo simples ou complexo por causa disso, ele pode por exemplo delegar o acionamento para as aplicações que estão rodando ou para a aplicação que está em primeiro plano apenas, e aí é problema da aplicação o que fazer.

Pode ser que a aplicação ignore isso ou pode ser que ela nem esteja preparada para receber esta notificação que uma tecla foi acionada, e pouco acontecerá. Geralmente há um limite do que pode ficar pendente e poderá recusar novos acionamentos ou ir jogando fora os mais antigos, ou ainda ter outra ação, não é algo que funciona igual sempre. Ela aceitando receber esse sinal tudo é possível ser feito, o código pode ser bem escrito ou mal escrito e fazer algo bom ou ruim, ocupar memória ou não.

Em resumo, o acionamento da tecla nada tem a ver diretamente com o consumo de memória.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).