# Retorno de uma simples função javascript não funcionando

Tags: javascript

Tenho o trecho de código abaixo que realiza uma chamada para o método `findCustomers(term, isNumber));`

```
if(isSequenceNumber(term) && term.length >= 6){
    var data = findCustomers(term, true);
    console.log(data);
    response(data);
}else{
    var data = findCustomers(term, false);
    console.log(data);
    response(data);
}
```

O método que não está retornando nada se encontra abaixo:

```
function findCustomers(term, isNumber){
    $.ajax({
        url: appContext + "/auth/search-customer-by-service",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            term: term,
            isNumber: isNumber
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                // Com resultados de clientes.
                var customerArray = new Array(data.length);
                var i = 0;
                data.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var newObject = {
                        label: entry.fullName + " " + "[" + entry.email + "]",
                        idCustomer: entry.idCustomer,
                        hasAvailableService: entry.hasAvailableService,
                    };
                    customerArray[i] = newObject;
                    i++;
                });
                return customerArray;
            } else {
                // Sem resultados de clientes.
                var notFoundArray = new Array(1);
                var notFoundObject = {
                        label: "Nenhum cliente encontrado",
                        idCustomer: 0,
                        hasAvailableService: "",
                };
                notFoundArray[0] = notFoundObject;
                return notFoundArray;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Vale a pena salientar que a requisição feita pelo AJAX retorna dados concretos, mas o retorno na chamada da função sempre está sendo `undefinied`

### EDITADO

Depois de entender a natureza do problema em função das respostas propostas abaixo eu chamei a função na qual realiza a requisição AJAX via função anonima desta forma:

```
findCustomers(term, true, function(response){
    console.log(response);
    response(response);
});
```

Mas mesmo assim ainda não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Acredito que está sendo retornando `undefined` pois a função `$.ajax` é assíncrona, ou seja, não é executada na hora. Neste caso, o retorno realmente é nada. O que você deveria ter era uma callback dentro de `success` do seu ajax onde você realiza a função com os resultados. Nesse caso, a sua função `$.ajax` é chamada e retornada no mesmo momento mas o retorno do `success` não retorna pra nada já que é uma callback. Você pode tentar colocar o parâmetro `async` como false. Veja [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Na verdade, me equivoquei nas palavras. Não é que não é executada na hora mas sim o resultado que você espera não é imediata.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu, sem sombra de dúvidas que o problema é este. Mas infelizmente a solução do async no meu caso não funcionou.

Comment: @fernandosavio, de fato a naturaza do problema e a mesma. Obrigado

Comment: Da para criar uma promise dessa requisição ajax, o if/else está dentro de outra função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
if(isSequenceNumber(term) && term.length >= 6){
    var data = findCustomers(term, true, resultado);
}else{
    var data = findCustomers(term, false, resultado);
}

function resultado(data) {
    console.log(data);
    response(data);
}

function findCustomers(term, isNumber, resultado){
    $.ajax({
        url: appContext + "/auth/search-customer-by-service",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            term: term,
            isNumber: isNumber
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                // Com resultados de clientes.
                var customerArray = new Array(data.length);
                var i = 0;
                data.forEach(function(entry) {
                    var newObject = {
                        label: entry.fullName + " " + "[" + entry.email + "]",
                        idCustomer: entry.idCustomer,
                        hasAvailableService: entry.hasAvailableService,
                    };
                    customerArray[i] = newObject;
                    i++;
                });
                resultado(customerArray);
            } else {
                // Sem resultados de clientes.
                var notFoundArray = new Array(1);
                var notFoundObject = {
                        label: "Nenhum cliente encontrado",
                        idCustomer: 0,
                        hasAvailableService: "",
                };
                notFoundArray[0] = notFoundObject;
                resultado(notFoundArray);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Ou seja, sua função resultado terá realmente o que será feito, sendo uma callback apenas quando `success` da sua requisição `$.ajax` for chamada.

**PS:** Talvez a sintaxe não esteja perfeita pois escrevi aqui mesmo na SO, mas acredito que vá funcionar.

Se você não fosse criar uma nova array dentro de success, você poderia simplesmente trocar aquela função toda por `success: resultado` que daria no mesmo. Você pode fazer tal rotina dentro da sua função também, aí é com você.

Uma referência boa: [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback)

Comment: Perfeito Kevin. De fato era isto que eu estava precisando. O link também foi de grande ajuda. Obrigado