# Função com requisição em AJAX que retorna outra função para manipulação de objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho uma função que usa AJAX para retornar dados de um banco de dados. Os dados são processados e retornados em JSON e, a partir daí, faço as devidas manipulações. Assim:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'post',
        statusCode: {
            200: function(res) {
                res.forEach(function(data){
                    // do something
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

O que quero saber é como executar uma outra função que manipule esses dados retornados em JSON ao chamar essa função, tipo como fazemos quando capturamos um clique:

```
$('seletor').on('click', function(){
    // do something...
})
```

E com minha função, seria algo assim (nem tenho certeza se isso está correto):

```
getData(function(){
    // do something with JSON data...
})
```

Não sei como declarar essa função e "disponibilizar" esse objeto para ser manipulado com outra função.

Utilizo códigos de estado nos cabeçalhos HTTP para realizar diferentes funções em diferentes cenários. Aí tem só o código 200 de sucesso, e é onde pretendo manipular o objeto JSON retornado pela requisição com AJAX.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: opa, foi mal, era pra outra pergunta, postei errado

Comment: independendo do codigo, vc quer executar um função ao termino da requisição ajax isso?

Comment: Na resposta da requisição, você está esperando uma array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o enunciado da sua questão, eu acho que você está atrás de definir a famosa, *callback*. Você pode achar uma definição para *callback* [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/125486) do @Sergio no próprio *StackOverflow em Português*:

> Callback é uma função que é usada como "callback". Ela é tipicamente
>   passada como argumento de outra função e/ou chamada quando um evento
>   for acontecido, ou quando uma parte de código receber uma resposta de
>   que estava à espera.

**OBS.: isso é somente um trecho inicial da resposta**

No caso, você terá que definir o parâmetro `callback` para a função `getData`, e no recebimento da resposta, você "chama" o parâmetro. Ficando dessa forma:

```
function getData(callback) { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'script.php', 
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json'
        statusCode: { 
            200: callback
        } 
    });
}
getData(function(data) {
    //coloca o código para manipular os dados
});
```

A opção `dataType` com o valor `"json"`, garante que a resposta será um objeto JSON/JavaScript.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Era tão fácil assim e eu me perdi todo... Valeu! =D

Answer (score 0):

pelo q entendi voce quer manipular o JSON que o Ajax retorna.
então o método seria mais ou menos assim:

```
function getData() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'post',
    statusCode: {
        200: function(res) {
            res.forEach(function(data){
                // do something
            })
        }
    }
}).done(ajaxDone)          // Funcao que trata caso a requisição ajax for completada
  .fail(ajaxFail); // função que trata caso a requisição ajax der falha

}

 function ajaxDone(data){
   /* Aqui voce trata aos dados como quiser vc pode verificar com if`s
    o status do retorno isso se seu retorno contiver uma variável de status */
   if(data.status == 'OK'){
      // faz algo
   }
   if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
   // faz outra coisa
   }
 }

  function ajaxFail(error){
   /* Aqui você pode tratar o erro caso o ajax não seja concluído */

 }
```

Qualquer erro ou duvida deixe um comentário, ou se não for isso tbm. :D

Comment: Isso é útil... Mas não quero manipular o retorno do JSON de diferentes maneiras, por isso queria saber como retornar os dados e utilizar em qualquer função de callback. Mas obrigado pela ajuda!