# JavaScript possui o equivalente à list comprehension do Python?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte código em Python:

```py
tag = 3
stack = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,55,3,4,3]
results = [i for i, x in enumerate(stack) if x == tag]
```

Esse código irá gerar a seguinte lista: `[2, 5, 9, 11]`.

E quero fazer o mesmo em JavaScript. Eu sei como fazer:

```js
var tag = 3;
var stack = [1,2,3,4,5,3,2,4,55,3,4,3];
var results = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < stack.length ; i++) {
    if(stack[i] == tag) {
        results.push(i);
    }
}
console.log(results);
```

Mas tem como fazer da mesma forma elegante que é feito em Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que foi feito em Python é chamado compreensão de listas. Essa sintaxe não existe em JavaScript, mas você pode obter resultados similares com métodos como `map`, `filter` e `reduce`, embora "elegante" seja arbitrário.

Exemplo:

```js
tag = 3
stack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 55, 3, 4, 3]
result = stack.reduce((arr, x, i) => x == tag ? arr.concat(i) : arr, [])
      
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 6):

Em Python isso é chamado de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), e é algo que o JavaScript não tem (já "chegou a ter" mais ou menos, como veremos mais abaixo).

Então o jeito é fazer um *loop* normal mesmo, como você já fez. Claro que dá para fazer de outras maneiras, como por exemplo usando [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) e [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var tag = 3;
var stack = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 55, 3, 4, 3];
var results = stack.map((_, indice) => indice).filter(i => stack[i] == tag);
console.log(results); // [ 2, 5, 9, 11 ]
```

O `map` mapeia os elementos para seus respectivos índices, e o `filter` filtra aqueles que satisfazem a condição.

Mas eu acho isso uma complicação desnecessária. O seu código eu considero a melhor opção, por ser mais simples, legível e sem "firulas" desnecessárias - sei que o código é "maior" que as outras opções, mas isso não deveria ser o único critério para escolher entre um ou outro. [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052).

Usando `map` e `filter`, você acaba fazendo dois *loops* (para um array com N elementos, são feitas 2N iterações), e cada uma dessas funções retorna outro array. No caso acima, `map` gera um array "intermediário", que é usado por `filter`, para só então gerar o array final com os resultados. Sem contar que ambas recebem como parâmetro uma função de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/112052), que é executada para cada elemento do array (ou seja, para um array com N elementos, serão 2N chamadas de função: N chamadas para o *callback* do `map` e mais N chamadas para o *callback* do `filter`).

O mesmo vale para `reduce` da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365307/112052): embora ele só percorra o array uma vez, ainda sim para cada elemento é feita uma chamada de função. Só isso faz com que estas soluções sejam mais lentas.

[Fiz um teste básico](https://jsbench.me/2qks7raiac/1) e o seu *loop* simples foi de longe o mais rápido de todos. Já o `reduce` foi o mais lento (muito mais, inclusive - testei no Chrome, pode ser que varie conforme o ambiente).

É claro que, para arrays pequenos sendo processados poucas vezes, a diferença será imperceptível. Mas é importante ter em mente esses detalhes, e não usar algo só porque o código fica menor, ou porque é "mais legal", ou porque "funcional é melhor", etc. O código pode até ficar menor, mas muitas vezes ficará pior ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/522805/112052)).

---

## O JavaScript já "teve" isso, mas não tem mais...

Apenas como curiosidade, existia uma proposta para incluir algo similar no JavaScript (chamado de "Array comprehension"), porém **nunca chegou a ser oficialmente incorporado à linguagem**. É possível ver a documentação no [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20210428193826/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Array_comprehensions) (pois o [link original da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) nem existe mais, inclusive se vc clicar nele, será redirecionado para a seção de ["*Deprecated and obsolete features*"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#legacy_generator_and_iterator)).

Lá podemos ver que há um aviso dizendo que não é uma funcionalidade padronizada, e que chegou a funcionar por algum tempo em alguns *browsers* (é mencionado o Firefox, das versões 30 a 58), mas depois foi removido, e permanece assim até hoje.

No Web Archive também podemos ver alguns exemplos da sintaxe, bem próxima à do Python:

```js
[for (x of iterable) x]
[for (x of iterable) if (condition) x]
[for (x of iterable) for (y of iterable) x + y]
```

A diferença, como pode-se ver, era que a expressão ficava no final, enquanto que no Python ela fica no início. Ou seja, em Python seria assim:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 30]
doubledEvens = [i * 2 for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0]
print(doubledEvens); # [4, 44, 60]
```

Enquanto que o equivalente em JavaScript seria assim:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 21, 22, 30];
var doubledEvens = [for (i of numbers) if (i % 2 === 0) i * 2];
console.log(doubledEvens); // [4, 44, 60]
```

Um detalhe interessante é que para iterar pelos elementos, somente o [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) era permitido.

E versões mais antigas da proposta ainda sugeriam uma sintaxe igual à do Python (com a expressão no início, antes do `for`).

Porém nada disso foi pra frente e o JavaScript atualmente não possui tal recurso. Portanto, as alternativas são as já listadas acima e na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/365307/112052) (ou o *loop* simples que você fez, que - repito - ainda acho a melhor opção, pelos motivos já citados).

Comment: Você desenterrou isso de onde? :D Nunca tinha visto isso...

Comment: @LuizFelipe Foi meio aleatório, estava pesquisando outra coisa e sem querer esbarrei no assunto. Aí lembrei desta pergunta e resolvi responder :-)

Answer (score -4):

Achei interessante ver nas respostas que eu faria de outra forma. Deixo anotado aqui:

```js
// o mais lógico seria iniciar pelo final da list comprehension
results = stack.filter((v,i) => v == tag).map((v,i) => i) // ops, o filter eliminou os itens diferentes e perdemos o indice dos itens certos!

// mantem apenas os indices certos, em suas posições, pra depois eliminar o resto
results = stack.map((v,i) => v == tag? i : null).filter(v => v)
```

Comment: Senhor, a pergunta é se existe ou não em javascript algo similar ao artefato list comprehension do Python, não foi um pedido de transpilacão. Os códigos transpilados são apenas ilustrações auxiliares na explicação de um conceito.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ultima linha da pergunta: "Mas tem como fazer da mesma forma elegante que é feito em Python?"