# Melhor prática de criar objeto a partir de reduce

Tags: javascript, objetos

Escrevi um algoritmo usando `reduce` que cria um objeto com outros dois objetos dentro, entretanto  achei ilegível.

Em busca de inspiração para refatorar o algoritmo acabei pesquisando no codegrepper e google, mas não obtive.

Eu acredito que o algoritmo seja relativamente fácil e usado dentro de sistemas, se alguém fazer sugestão ficarei grato.

Segue código que escrevi de primeira mão:

```js
let isbns = [
    '64646464',
    '978-8575228050',
    '978-8573076103',
    '6586057043'
]
let links = ['Nenhum resultado para 64646464.',
    '/Problemas-Cl%C3%A1ssicos-Ci%C3%AAncia-Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Python/dp/8575228056',
    '/Padr%C3%B5es-Projetos-Solu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-Reutiliz%C3%A1veis-Orientados/dp/8573076100',
    '/Migrando-Sistemas-Monol%C3%ADticos-Para-Microsservi%C3%A7os/dp/6586057043'
]

const validatingIsbn = (isbns, links) => {
    let invalidos = {}, validos = {}
    return isbns.reduce((obj, isbn, index) => {
        let result 
        if (links[index] == `Nenhum resultado para ${[isbn]}.`) {
            let invalido = Object.assign(invalidos, {[isbn] : links[index]})
            result = {...obj, invalido}
        } else {
            let valido = Object.assign(validos, {[isbn] : links[index]})
            result = {...obj, valido}
        }
        return result
    }, {})
}

console.log(validatingIsbn(isbns, links))
```

Answer (score 9):

A melhor prática para usar `reduce` é: não utilize `reduce` quando não cabe a utilização desse método.

`reduce` é um método bastante flexível, você pode utilizá-lo para criar novos arrays, criar objetos, filtrar elementos, aplicar operações matemáticas, mas o método não é muito idiomático para a maioria dessas utilizações (sendo a última a exceção).

Utilizá-lo para calcular o total dos valores contidos num array de objetos é simples e idiomático, você poderia até chamá-lo de elegante. Utilizá-lo para criar um objeto indexado com os valores do array, nem tanto, não há ganhos em legibilidade nem linhas de código.

Então, minha sugestão, algo totalmente subjetivo e não cabível a resposta desse site, mas que eu estou dando de toda forma, é não utilizar o `reduce` para esses cenários.

E aqui tem uma sugestão de como refatorar a função para uma forma que eu vejo como mais legível:

```
function validatingIsbn(isbns, links) {
    const validos = {}, invalidos = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        const categoria = links[i] === `Nenhum resultado para ${isbns[i]}` ? invalidos : validos;
        categoria[isbns[i]] = links[i];
    }

    return { validos, invalidos };
}
```

Comment: Na verdade eu diria que é cabível ao site sim porque seu argumento tem certo fundamento por trás. Sair utilizando `reduce` para todo lado, como muita gente faz, pode prejudicar bastante a legibilidade do código. Boa conclusão e resposta útil. :)

Comment: Perfeito, não só o `for` é mais simples e claro, como na maioria das vezes é mais eficiente, pois com `reduce` há uma chamada de função para cada elemento do array (esse custo geralmente é negligenciado porque para poucos arrays pequenos, a diferença não é perceptível). De qualquer forma, nesse caso - e em muitos outros - o ganho em legibilidade é outra vantagem do loop simples. E como já disseram, sua resposta é cabível ao site sim, pois tem fundamentação (ao contrário de muitos "fanáticos" que defendem o uso de `reduce` pra tudo, alegando que  "funcional é melhor" e outras falácias...)

Comment: Vale o mesmo pra `map` e outros "encurtamentos" de código sem sentido. Infelizmente o pessoal fraco de teoria usa essas coisas indiscriminadamente o tempo todo (infelizmente a grande maioria dos "programadores" nunca vai ser de verdade, mas o mercado absorve por absurda escasses de gente qualificada). Não é questão só de legibilidade, e sim de completo desperdício de recursos. Usar reduce, map e assemelhados onde cabe perfeitamente um for geralmente é sinal de despreparo.

Comment: Segue um comparativo entre o `for` simples vs `reduce` (o `for` é bem mais rápido): https://jsbench.me/k7ks9594pm/1