# Como otimizar um script node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Olá, gostaria da ajuda dos usuários para otimizar um script que fiz em node.js. Não entendo muito da linguagem e fiz um sistema bem amador que está um pouco lento.

```
var express = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var request = require('request');

var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var xml = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml.Parser();

express.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Dedicated server of Turn Network running!');
});

var tMusic;
var aTurn = {
    url: {
        history: '../../../Playlist/pgm/Montagem/MusicHistory.xml',
        current: '../../../Playlist/pgm/current.xml'
    },
    startServer: function(){
        aTurn.readData();

        setTimeout(function(){
            aTurn.updateData();
        }, 3000);
    },
    readData: function(){
        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                tMusic = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;
            });
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            aTurn.readData();
        }, 1000);
    },
    updateData: function(){
        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                var current = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;
                var split = current.split(' - ');

                if(tMusic === current){
                }
                else if(tMusic == undefined || tMusic.length <= 0){
                    aTurn.emitData();
                }
                else{
                    aTurn.emitData();
                }
            });
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            aTurn.updateData();
        }, 1000);
    },
    emitData: function(){
        function album(music){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                request('http://source.localhost/provider/saveArt/'+music+'', function (error, response, result){
                    data = JSON.parse(result);
                    resolve(data['returnAlbum']);
                });
            });
        }
        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.current, function(err, data){
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                var music = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'] + ' - ' + result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'];
                var music = music.toString();

                var startTime = result['Playlist']['OnAir'][0]['CurIns'][0]['StartedTime'];
                var startTime = startTime.toString().split(' ');

                var endTime = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0].$.SchedTime;
                var endTime = endTime.split(' ');

                var nextArtist = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'];
                var nextMusic = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'];

                album(music).then(function(nextAlbum){
                    io.emit('updateNext', {
                        'nextArtist': nextArtist.toString(), 
                        'nextMusic': nextMusic.toString(),
                        'nextAlbum': nextAlbum
                    });
                });
                io.emit('updateTime', {
                    'startTime': startTime[1], 
                    'endTime': endTime[1],
                    'maxTime': ''
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    aTurn.emitData();
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Client server running on port 3000!');
});

aTurn.startServer();
```

É um sistema que envia uma comunicação em socket sempre que tMusic mudar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Ficaria extremamente agradecido.

Comment: qual a necessidade de haver `setTimeout(function(){ ... }, 3000)` para então executar `updateData()` e `readData()` ??

Comment: Para que antes de serem executadas, as mesmas já tenham lido os devidos arquivos. Pois sem o setTimeout estava dando undefined.

Comment: Nesse caso você deveria usar o callback do `fs.readFile` para executar o próximo passo somente depois que a leitura terminar. Usar o `setTimeout` aí é um gambiarra das fortes.

Comment: hahaha, foi bem na gambiarra mesmo, sou muito novato nisso.

Comment: comece usando fs.readFileSync e fs.writeFileSync para se livrar desse set timeout

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sugiro fortemente que você estude callbacks e procure entender realmente seu funcionamento. Seu código tem vários `setTimeout`s que não deveriam existir, e a sua lógica para ler e atualizar continuamente as coisas pode ser simplificada monstruosamente usando eles.

Corrigi o código com isso em mente, ficou assim:

```
var express = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var request = require('request');

var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');
var xml = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml.Parser();

express.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Dedicated server of Turn Network running!');
});

var tMusic;
var aTurn = {
    url: {
        history: '../../../Playlist/pgm/Montagem/MusicHistory.xml',
        current: '../../../Playlist/pgm/current.xml'
    },
    startServer: function(){
        aTurn.watchData(function(result) {
            aTurn.updateData(result);
        });
    },
    watchData: function(callback) {
        fs.watchFile(aTurn.url.history, function () {
            fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
                parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                    tMusic = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;

                    if (callback)
                        callback(result);
                });
            });
        });
    },
    updateData: function() {
        aTurn.emitData();
    },
    emitData: function(){
        function album(music){
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                request('http://source.localhost/provider/saveArt/' + music, function (error, response, result){
                    var data = JSON.parse(result);
                    resolve(data['returnAlbum']);
                });
            });
        }

        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.current, function(err, data){
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                var music = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'] + ' - ' + result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'];

                var startTime = result['Playlist']['OnAir'][0]['CurIns'][0]['StartedTime'];
                var startTime = startTime.toString().split(' ');

                var endTime = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0].$.SchedTime;
                var endTime = endTime.split(' ');

                var nextArtist = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Artist'];
                var nextMusic = result['Playlist']['Next'][0]['NextMusic'][0]['Music'][0]['Title'];

                album(music).then(function(nextAlbum){
                    io.emit('updateNext', {
                        'nextArtist': nextArtist.toString(), 
                        'nextMusic': nextMusic.toString(),
                        'nextAlbum': nextAlbum
                    });
                });

                io.emit('updateTime', {
                    'startTime': startTime[1], 
                    'endTime': endTime[1],
                    'maxTime': ''
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    aTurn.emitData();
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Client server running on port 3000!');
});

aTurn.startServer();
```

Claramente, como não sei o formato dos seus arquivos nem o resultado esperado do código, não tenho como testar que realmente funciona pro que você precisa, mas em termos de lógica assim fica melhor estruturado.

---

### Correções feitas

Os problemas estavam basicamente todos em volta das funções `readData` e `updateData`. O primeiro:

#### 1. `setTimeout` com objetivo de "faz um, depois faz o outro"

```
aTurn.readData();

setTimeout(function(){
    aTurn.updateData();
}, 3000);
```

Isso não se faz.

- *Primeiro problema:* Não é estável. Se algum dia, por ventura, seu `readData` demorar mais que 3 segundos para executar, o `updateData` vai rodar sem que ele tenha completado.
- *Segundo problema:* Para basicamente todo caso em que o timeout de fato funciona, você perde tempo esperando 3 segundos, quando na verdade o `readData` pode ter terminado em 5ms.

**Solução**

Adicione um *callback* à função `readData` que é chamado quando ela termina. Veja [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback) pergunta para mais informações sobre o que é o callback e onde ele é usado.

Nosso código refatorado fica:

```
aTurn.readData(function() {
    aTurn.updateData();
});
```

E no `readData`:

```
readData: function(callback) {
    fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
            tMusic = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;

            if (callback)
                callback();
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        aTurn.readData();
    }, 1000);
},
```

Veja que o callback só é útil se você quiser rodar outras coisas além do `updateData` logo após o `readData`, e houver necessidade de rodar coisas diferentes para cada chamada do `readData`. Caso contrário, você pode só chamar o `updateData` do `readData` logo:

```
readData: function() {
    fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
            tMusic = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;
            aTurn.updateData();
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        aTurn.readData();
    }, 1000);
},
```

### 2. `setTimeout` para ler arquivo de 1 em 1 segundo

```
readData: function() {
    fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
        // ...
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        aTurn.readData();
    }, 1000);
},
```

**Solução**

Se eu entendi o que você queria, a ideia disso aí é ler o arquivo a cada x segundos e atualizar as coisas quando ele muda, correto?

Nesse caso, você pode usar a função [`fs.watchFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener):

```
readData: function(callback) {
    fs.watchFile(aTurn.url.history, function () {
        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
            // ...
        });
    });
},
```

Vale notar que o `fs.watchFile` pode não ser consistente em todas as plataformas, como a própria documentação declara. Leia com atenção a documentação dessa função.

### 3. Função `updateData`

```
    updateData: function(){
        fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data){
            parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
                var current = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;
                var split = current.split(' - ');

                if(tMusic === current){
                }
                else if(tMusic == undefined || tMusic.length <= 0){
                    aTurn.emitData();
                }
                else{
                    aTurn.emitData();
                }
            });
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            aTurn.updateData();
        }, 1000);
    },
```

Essa função inteira é redundante com as mudanças que fizemos no `readData` para chamar callback.

Veja que a leitura do arquivo pode sumir, já que lemos o arquivo no `readData` e podemos passar essa informação adiante via callback:

```
readData: function(callback) {
  // ...
  fs.readFile(aTurn.url.history, function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function(err, result){
        tMusic = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;

        if (callback)
            callback(result);
    });
  });
  // ...
}
```

Assim, usamos o `data` no `updateData`, sem ter que ler o arquivo de novo (que geralmente é uma operação bem cara, por sinal):

```
    startServer: function(){
        aTurn.watchData(function(result) {
            aTurn.updateData(result);
        });
    },
    // ...
    updateData: function(result) {
        var current = result['MusicHistory']['Item0'][0].$.Music;
        var split = current.split(' - ');

        if(tMusic === current){
        }
        else if(tMusic == undefined || tMusic.length <= 0){
            aTurn.emitData();
        }
        else {
            aTurn.emitData();
        }
    }
```

Agora temos mais um problema: esse `if` que não tem sentido nenhum.

veja que `if (...) {}`, sem código entre as `{}`, pode sempre ser reduzido a um código mais simples: ``. Pois é, nada. Some com ele.

Somado a isso, nosso `tMusic` é sempre atualizado logo antes do `updateData`, logo de toda forma nunca teríamos `current != tMusic`.

Temos:

```
if (tMusic == undefined || tMusic.length <= 0) {
    aTurn.emitData();
} else {
    aTurn.emitData();
}
```

Agora olha que legal, se `tMusic == undefined || tMusic.length <= 0`, então `emitData`. Se não, `emitData` também! Por que não?

Pois é, isso não é um `if`, é um `aTurn.emitData();` com passos extras.

No fim, nossa função `updateData` vira isso:

```
    updateData: function() {
        aTurn.emitData();
    },
```

Ou seja, não precisa dela. Só chamar a `emitData` direto.

*Nota:* também não precisamos mais do `setTimeout`, porque a função é chamada toda vez que o `readData` é executado, e aquela função já repete!

### Observações

- Com a refatoração, fica claro que a variável `tMusic` não é usada e é inútil.
- A função `emitData` sempre avança para a próxima música a partir da atual (que imagino estar no arquivo `current`), e não usa as informações do `readData` e `updateData`. Isso leva a crer que, na verdade, as funções `readData` e `updateData` são desnecessárias (na verdade, a `updateData` com certeza é, como já vimos).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, de coração! Além de ter dado certo, aprendi bastante com usa explicação! Abraços.