# Está função está usando o conceito de callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arrayDobrado = array.map(function(num) {
    return num * 2;
});
```

Comment: Acho que vai ajudá-lo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/99718