# Jquery espera a função acabar para exibir uma imagem. Como resolver?

Tags: jquery

Opa, estou fazendo um projeto de um **jogo da memória** que necessita que uma imagem seja mudada no momento de um click utilizando *Jquery*.

O jogo se baseia em clicar em `divs`, e exibir as imagens dentro delas, **duas por vez**. Caso sejam iguais, **elas se mantém à mostra**, caso sejam diferentes **elas são escondidas**.

Ao clicar na primeira `div`, a imagem dentro dela é exibida normalmente, ao clicar na segunda `div`, o sistema verifica se as imagens forem iguais, se sim, elas ficam a amostra, caso contrário, o sistema esconde as duas imagens clicadas alguns segundos depois.

Só que isso não acontece, provavelmente, pelo fato da imagem só carregar ao fim da função do click da `div`. ( código abaixo).

```js
$(".card").click(function () {
        tent++;
        var idCard = $(this).attr('id');
        revelarImg(idCard);
        desabilitarClick(idCard);

        if (tent == 2) {
            if (ganhou(primTent, idCard)) {
                pontuacao++;
                if (pontuacao == 9)
                    gameWin();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(esconderCards(primTent, idCard), 3000);
                habilitarClicks(primTent, idCard);
            }
            tent = 0;
        }
        else {
            primTent = idCard;
        }

    });
```

Notem, que a função que revela a imagem é chamada em todo click, mas a mudança só é realmente efetuada ao final da função. Se o usuário errou ( quando for a segunda tentativa dele), é chamada a função `esconderCards()` que anula a outra que as revela.  ( códigos das funções abaixo )

```js
function revelarImg(id) {
    $("#" + id +"> img").attr("src", arrayImgs[id]);
     }

    function esconderCards(primeira, segunda) {
    $("#" + primeira +"> img").attr("src","imgs/front.png");
    $("#" + segunda +"> img").attr("src","imgs/front.png");
```

Segue o `html` das `divs` com as imagens:

```html
<div class="card" id="0">
            <img src="imgs/front.png">
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="1">
                <img src="imgs/front.png">
        </div>
        ...
```

Como posso exibir a segunda imagem sem esperar a função terminar e se "auto anular"?

Comment: Cara edita sua pergunta, coloca o html/css tb de forma que a gente consiga simular seu problema ai, vai facilitar para alguém te responder

Comment: @hugocsl , feito, não inseri css pois são apenas posições na tela, não inseri nada a partir deles

Comment: Não cheguei a assistir, mas acredito que esse video pode te ajudar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0I6Z06N0kM

Comment: @CaiqueRomero em que momento o "Change" seria disparado? Eu então, excluiria minha função revelar, e colocaria o trecho direto no click?

Comment: Tá meio confuso isso. O que determina que uma carta é igual a outra?

Comment: @Sam , se o html das duas divs são iguais. A função booleana ganhou é uma comparação entre os htmls.

Comment: Seria melhor vc editar a pergunta e colocar o código todo de forma que se possa reproduzir o sistema.

Comment: Da uma olhada no exemplo que fiz, inclusive os links que coloquei, espero que te ajude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo bem simples, não utilizei um array pois achei ele desnecessário e coloquei uma função de [Callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/88202) na exibição da imagem, para exibir a mensagem ao ganhador após a exibição da imagem

Utilizei as funções [fadeIn](https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) | [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

```js
var tentativa = 0;
var cardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = "";
var idCardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = "";

$(".card").on("click", function(){
  //obtenho o cardSelecionado:
  var cardSelecionado = $(this).attr('data-img');
  var idCardSelecionado = $(this).attr('id');
  
  //Oculto o label e exibo a imagem do card selecionado
  $(this).children("label").hide();
  
  //utilizo a função fadeIn e defino uma funcao de callback, ou seja, uma função que será executada somente após o encerramento da animação.
  $(this).children("img").fadeIn(1400, function(){
    Tentativa(cardSelecionado, idCardSelecionado)
  });
  
});

function Tentativa(cardSelecionado, idCardSelecionado){
  tentativa++
  if(tentativa == 2){    
    if(cardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa == cardSelecionado
          && idCardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa != idCardSelecionado)
      {
        alert("Ganhou!!")
      }
    //Escondo campos e limpo as variaveis
    $(".card>img").fadeOut("slow", Limpar());
  }else{
    cardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = cardSelecionado;
    idCardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = idCardSelecionado;
  }
}
function Limpar(){
  $(".card>label").show();
  tentativa = 0;
  cardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = "";
  idCardSelecionadoPrimeiraTentativa = ""
}
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.card > img {
  width: 25px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card" data-img="troll" id="1">
  <label>CARD 1</label>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jWr67J8.png?1" alt="Meme Troll" />
</div>
<div class="card" data-img="challenge" id="2">
  <label>CARD 2</label>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/U3ZiZvu.jpg" class=".card" alt="Meme challenge"/>
</div>
<div class="card" data-img="challenge" id="3">
  <label>CARD 3</label>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/U3ZiZvu.jpg" class=".card" alt="Meme challenge"/>
</div>
<div class="card" data-img="troll" id="4">
  <label>CARD 4</label>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jWr67J8.png?1" alt="Meme Troll"/>
</div>
```