# Callback em função anônima retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, http, post, jwt, callback

Preciso criar duas funções.

Uma delas em que vou fazer uma requisição em Javascript para pegar um Bearer Token, e a segunda, vou usar o token para chamar outra função.

Porém, não estou conseguindo pegar o retorno da primeira função.

O código está essa forma:

```
function getAuthToken() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
  const params = {
    "login" : "admin",
    "password" : "123456"
  };

  $.ajaxSetup({
     headers:{
        'Accept': "application/json"
     }
  });

  $.post(url, params, function(response, status) {
    if(status == 'success') {
      return response.token
    }
  });
}

console.log(getAuthToken())
```

Sempre que dou o `console.log` para tentar pegar o resultado, dá um valor undefined.
Porém, se eu der um `console.log` dentro da própria função, sem dar o return, o retorno é o seguinte:

```
{
   login:"admin",
   password:"123456",
   id:101
}
```

A dificuldade que estou tendo é em pegar o **response** e retornar na função principal, para depois eu conseguir pegar este token e usar em uma segunda função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

João,

Ao utiliza o `$.post`, você está utilizando uma função assíncrona, logo ele vai passar por esse trecho do código e não vai esperar o retorno da API, o [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback) do post é executado de forma assíncrona, por isso ao colocar um `console.log` dentro do mesmo você consegue ver o `response`.

Em casos como esse você pode utilizar de `async`/`await`, declarando a função que consome a API como assíncrona e ao consumir a API e a própria função, utilizar do `await`.

Veja o exemplo um exemplo abaixo:

```js
//Declaração da função getAuthToken como assíncrona
async function getAuthToken() {
  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  const params = {
    "login" : "admin",
    "password" : "123456"
  };

  $.ajaxSetup({
     headers:{
        "Accept": "application/json"
     }
  });

  //Ao consultar a API, utilizo do await, para esperar o retorno da API
  return await $.post(url, params);
}

//Função anônima assíncrona, pois só posso utilizar do await dentro de uma função assíncrona
(async () => {
  console.log( await getAuthToken() );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Referências:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

---

Se você procurar aqui mesmo no stackoverflow, vai ver que tem muito conteúdo sobre async/await do JS: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=async+await+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: Também poderia declarar o getAuthToken como async, para não usar uma função anônima.