# Função retornando undefined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

Olá, sou iniciante em js e estou com problema na seguinte função checkRequired(inputArr), por algum motivo ela retorna undefined. Já tentei de várias maneiras achar o erro utilizando o console.log e fazendo algumas alterações no código, mas não obtive sucesso
Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

```
function checkRequired(inputArr){

    let isRequired = true;
    
    inputArr.forEach(function(input){
        if(input.value.trim() === ""){
            showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
            isRequired = false;
            return isRequired;
        }
        else{
            showSuccess(input);
            isRequired = true;
            return isRequired;
        }
    });
}

function addTransaction(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();

    if(checkRequired([text, amount])){
        
        const transaction = {
            id: generateID(),
            text: text.value,
            amount: +amount.value
        }
        transactions.push(transaction);
        if(checkRequired([text, amount]) === undefined){
            addTransactionDOM(transaction);
        }
        updateValues();
        updateLocalStorage();
        
        text.value = "";
        amount.value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) serve para fazer alguma coisa com cada elemento de um array. Essa "alguma coisa" é um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/112052): uma função que é passada como argumento para `forEach`, e executada para cada elemento do array.

O `return`, no caso, está dentro do *callback*. Ou seja, isso aqui:

```
inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.value.trim() === "") {
        showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
        isRequired = false;
        return isRequired;
    } else {
        showSuccess(input);
        isRequired = true;
        return isRequired;
    }
});
```

Seria equivalente a fazer isso:

```
function fazAlgo(input) {
    if (input.value.trim() === "") {
        showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
        isRequired = false;
        return isRequired;
    } else {
        showSuccess(input);
        isRequired = true;
        return isRequired;
    }
}
for (const input of inputArr) {
    fazAlgo(input);
}
```

Você está chamando a função várias vezes (uma para cada elemento do array). A função retorna, mas o seu retorno é ignorado (não é guardado em nenhum lugar).

E o retorno do *callback* não é o retorno do `forEach`. Até porque `forEach` não retorna nada (ele só serve para executar alguma coisa em todos os elementos).

---

Pelo que entendi, você quer que `checkRequired` retorne `true` se todos os campos estiverem preenchidos, e `false` se algum deles - qualquer um - estiver vazio. Então bastaria fazer:

```
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    for (const input of inputArr) {
        if (input.value.trim() === "") { // se algum campo for vazio, retorna false
            showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
            return false;
        } else showSuccess(input);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Você percorre os campos com `for...of`, e se algum deles for vazio, retorne `false` (não precisa verificar o restante).

Se chegou ao final do `for`, é porque todos estão preenchidos, então posso retornar `true`.

Claro que também pode ser feito com um `for` "tradicional":

```
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        let input = inputArr[i];
        if (input.value.trim() === "") { // se algum campo for vazio, retorna false
            showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
            return false;
        } else showSuccess(input);
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

O detalhe é que a função acima é interrompida logo que encontrar um campo não preenchido.

Mas se a ideia é sempre percorrer todos os campos, mostrando a mensagem de sucesso ou de erro para cada um deles, basta fazer assim:

```
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    let required = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        let input = inputArr[i];
        if (input.value.trim() === "") { // se algum campo for vazio, required é false
            showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
            required = false;
        } else showSuccess(input);
    }
    return required;
}
```

Repare que não faz sentido setar `required = true` dentro do `else`. E se o primeiro campo não está preenchido mas o segundo sim? Se tivesse `required = true` dentro do `else`, a função retornaria `true`, mesmo tendo um campo vazio. A ideia é que, se encontrar um campo vazio, `required` seja `false` e não mude mais (pois basta ter um campo vazio para que a verificação falhe). Somente se todos estiverem preenchidos, a função retorna `true`.

A diferença é que dentro do `if` não tem mais o `return`, então a função não é interrompida. Neste caso, serão mostradas as mensagens para todos os campos, estejam eles vazios ou não.

Comment: Opa hkotsubo, muito obrigado pela ajuda. E olhando novamente, realmente o return não pertencia a função checkRequired, e sim a função callback. Eu apenas tirei o return da callback, pus na função e cheguei onde eu queria, também testei a sua solução com o laço for. Não sei qual seria o mais recomendado para essa situação, pq ainda não manjo de refinamento de código. Mas agradeço novamente.

Comment: @MarceloCabral Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis. E nesse caso eu acho o `for` mais simples e claro que `forEach`, pois não precisa de um callback sendo que dá pra fazer tudo no próprio loop

Answer (score 0):

O valor está voltando undefined porque você não está dando retorno na função, que você colocou alguns `return` mas eles estão retornando o valor para o callback da função `forEach` e a sua função `checkRequired()` não tem return, tente isso aqui:

```
function checkRequired(inputArr){

let isRequired = true;

inputArr.forEach(function(input){
    if(input.value.trim() === ""){
        showError(input, `Esse campo deve ser preenchido`);
        isRequired = false;
        return isRequired
    }
    else{
        showSuccess(input);
        isRequired = true;
        return isRequired;
    }
 });

 return isRequired;
}
```

Comment: Opa Jason Rabelo. Olhando novamente aqui, o return não pertencia a função checkRequired(), e sim a callback, testei com o seu código e deu certo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda